# Check on which part was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can you check in JS or JQuery in which part of the image was clicked?

For example we have this: [Picture](http://www.wilde13-werbemittelkatalog.de/pictures/werbekugelschreiber.jpg)

Can you check if the user clicked on a specific pen? For example the red one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use of `image-mapping` is better for this kind of requirement. map the required area and link to required url. know more about `image-mapping` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: yup obvious, which IDE you use?

Comment: if you are using Dreamweaver, it is too easy to achieve, as you just directly mark on the image, and mark-up of pixels are automated.

Comment: eclipse with jsdt.

Comment: there are map generators in the inet ^^

Comment: thats great you found it.. you are always welcome mate. better add up a link, from where you are generating map links.

Comment: That's great.. This could be helpful for the community who are looking for this kind of result.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have at least three options:

1. Split the image into several images each with one pen, and then put them into a link that specifies the pen (e.g. `<a href="#red"><img src="redpen.jpg" /></a>`.
2. You can use an HTML map with area tags.
3. You can use the coordinates of your click event to decide which pen was clicked like described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4249711/387573

Comment: IMO 1 is the best - in case image will be resized, you don't need to wory about image map coords or click coords scaling

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an image map you can also just detect the click's x & y position relative to the image and then from there, work out what you want to do.

This will not be very accessible but it **will** work.

You can work out the relative x & y position of the click like so. (Try clicking on the yellow pen)

```js
var image = document.querySelector('img'); 

image.addEventListener('click', onClick, true);

function onClick(event){
  var imageBoundingRect = image.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    var x = event.pageX - imageBoundingRect.left;

    // We are not using the y co-ordinate but this is how you would get it.
    var y = event.pageY - imageBoundingRect.top;

 if (x >= 345 && x <= 380){
      alert('Clicked on the yellow pen.')
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.wilde13-werbemittelkatalog.de/pictures/werbekugelschreiber.jpg"/>
```