# Is their any way we can find the XY coordinates when we click on any position on pdf?

Tags: php

Kindly answer the above question. And if possible upload the code or any links you have which can be handy in coding.

Comment: On `php` it impossible. When and where you want found coordinates?

Comment: Using jquery is it possible ?

Comment: Yes. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element)

Comment: But you need to add wrapper of html where you will show pdf document to use jQuery