# Select area of an image and trigger a JS event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Is it possible, using either HTML canvas or Javascript, to click on part of an image and, depending on which part you clicked, it trigger a Javascript event?

So, for example;

If I have an image of a watch and the user clicks on the strap, this triggers a modal with content relating to the strap. Similarly, if they click on one of the watch hands, this triggers a different modal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery get mouse position within an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element)

Comment: You can place your image as css `background-image` property. Then you can add different divs inside your main container. [something like this](http://imgur.com/a/Q70eX). And then add onClick handler to your div

Comment: @ZhenyaTelegin That would work for the larger parts, but for the watch hands for example, which are much smaller and angled at various degrees, it wouldn't be quite as simple would it?

Comment: @DeanElliott i add [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43587875/7887530) to this question. I think splitting is easier :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the HTML tag to do so, Please check the `<area>` tag in html it might serve your purpose.

Check the below code may help you:

> [W3 Schools - Areamap](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap)

And you can also use `<canvas>` or `<svg>` with the help of [**Fabric.js**](http://fabricjs.com/) you can get the thing done in much more advance way.

Check this link you will get really cool stuff to do with image or canvas and svg:

> [MDN - Canvas API Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial)

Thanks

```js
function runfunc(planetId) {
  console.log('You selected:', planetId);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 2.8em !important; }
```

```html
<p>Click on the Sun or on one of the planets to see which one was selected.</p>

<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126"
     alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" id="Sun" onclick="runfunc(this.id)">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" id="Mercury" onclick="runfunc(this.id)">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" id="Venus" onclick="runfunc(this.id)">
</map>
```