# Detect click on resizable element's resize handle

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

It's super easy to make an element manually resizable using two lines of CSS. Like this:

```css
div {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  
  /*
  / Styling
  */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Now I'd like to detect when the element's resize handle is clicked by the user.

[image]

Oddly, Internet Explorer seems to be the only browser which attaches a `onResize` event to elements (other than the window). But even if other browsers implemented this, it's not exactly what I'm looking for as I need to know when the resize handle is clicked, not resized.

I've looked into attaching listeners to `mousedown` and checking the `currentTarget` vs `target` to see if they're different. No luck - both return the element itself.

My final, and last, last, last resort, is to inspect the click position to see if it's in the bottom-right corner of the element. But this seems ludicrous and unreliable.

Are there reliable methods for detecting clicks or events on an element's resize handle?

Comment: logically that would be part of the Shadow DOM, and only user created elements (_afaik_) can be open mode. So i doubt you can find a way to access the resizer besides the JS method (_checking mouse position_) you mention.

Comment: I resorted to your ludicrous last resort. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33378989/673991) gives the top-left click coordinates. Subtracting from offsetWidth, offsetHeight gives the bottom-right coordinates. Those are in the range 0-20 over the resize handle in major browsers. (I was rather desperate to prevent resizing from triggering the click-handler I use to begin contentEditable.)

Answer (score 2):

I checked this [**link**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/resizeobserver) and found an example on `resizeobserver`

```js
var ro = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (let entry of entries) {
    const cr = entry.contentRect;
    console.log(`Element size: ${cr.width}px x ${cr.height}px`);
   }
});
ro.observe(testId);
```

```css
#testId {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
}
```

```html
<div id="testId"></div>
```

Comment: Great find! Haven't seen that before. Unfortunately it only logs when the element is resized, not when the resize handle is clicked.

Comment: Also, `ResizeObserver` is currently [only supported in Chrome](https://caniuse.com/#feat=resizeobserver).

Comment: Update: It is now available on every browser that matters.