# How to restore default resize property to draggable div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, draggable

After adding basic dragging functionality to a div, the default css resize property no longer responds. Moving the mouse over the resize corner results in the cursor changing to the resize cursor, but the resize behaviour is completely overridden by dragging behaviour. Is there a way to restore this default resize behaviour so that it is not overridden?

(basic example based on w3schools dragging tutorial)
[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/kchaosdccd/pen/bGLWELV)

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("dragme"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#dragme {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="dragme">
  Click here to move
</div>
```

Comment: Here is an example that you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67463673/detect-if-user-trying-resize-a-draggable-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's impossible to have both working at the same time, if you keep the dragging possible on the whole card. In my opinion, the best way to achieve this, without being confusing, would be to enable dragging only on some part of the card. There is exemples on CodePen if you search for "drag resize".

Exemple: https://codepen.io/jkasun/pen/QrLjXP

```
window.onload = function() {
  initDragElement();
  initResizeElement();
};

function initDragElement() {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  var popups = document.getElementsByClassName("popup");
  var elmnt = null;
  var currentZIndex = 100; //TODO reset z index when a threshold is passed

  for (var i = 0; i < popups.length; i++) {
    var popup = popups[i];
    var header = getHeader(popup);

    popup.onmousedown = function() {
      this.style.zIndex = "" + ++currentZIndex;
    };

    if (header) {
      header.parentPopup = popup;
      header.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    }
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    elmnt = this.parentPopup;
    elmnt.style.zIndex = "" + ++currentZIndex;

    e = e || window.event;
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    if (!elmnt) {
      return;
    }

    e = e || window.event;
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = elmnt.offsetTop - pos2 + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1 + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }

  function getHeader(element) {
    var headerItems = element.getElementsByClassName("popup-header");

    if (headerItems.length === 1) {
      return headerItems[0];
    }

    return null;
  }
}

function initResizeElement() {
  var popups = document.getElementsByClassName("popup");
  var element = null;
  var startX, startY, startWidth, startHeight;

  for (var i = 0; i < popups.length; i++) {
    var p = popups[i];

    var right = document.createElement("div");
    right.className = "resizer-right";
    p.appendChild(right);
    right.addEventListener("mousedown", initDrag, false);
    right.parentPopup = p;

    var bottom = document.createElement("div");
    bottom.className = "resizer-bottom";
    p.appendChild(bottom);
    bottom.addEventListener("mousedown", initDrag, false);
    bottom.parentPopup = p;

    var both = document.createElement("div");
    both.className = "resizer-both";
    p.appendChild(both);
    both.addEventListener("mousedown", initDrag, false);
    both.parentPopup = p;
  }

  function initDrag(e) {
    element = this.parentPopup;

    startX = e.clientX;
    startY = e.clientY;
    startWidth = parseInt(
      document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element).width,
      10
    );
    startHeight = parseInt(
      document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element).height,
      10
    );
    document.documentElement.addEventListener("mousemove", doDrag, false);
    document.documentElement.addEventListener("mouseup", stopDrag, false);
  }

  function doDrag(e) {
    element.style.width = startWidth + e.clientX - startX + "px";
    element.style.height = startHeight + e.clientY - startY + "px";
  }

  function stopDrag() {
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener("mousemove", doDrag, false);
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener("mouseup", stopDrag, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Seems like the parent div cannot be both draggable and resizable concurrently. Playing off of your idea, I managed to get the behaviour I was looking for. 

I added a div to the card from which the entire card would be draggable. Then, I made that div cover the entire card. Just by doing that, the default resize behaviour was restored.

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/kchaosdccd/pen/bGLWELV)