# How to add a marker and show a div relative to a mouse click in vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a marker and a div next to the mouse click in vanilla Javascript.

Basically if the user clicks anywhere on the page, I want to add a marker where the click was made (a circular small div) and show a div next to the marker.

If the user presses somewhere else, the previous marker and div disappears and they basically appear in the new location of the click

- What I did:
- I created the div and I set the display to none, and now I'll try to make it appear when the user clicks anywhere on the page
- for the marker, I have this Jquery code that I will convert to vanilla JS:

```
  $(function(){
    $('body').click(function(e){
      var x = e.clientX;
      var y = e.clientY;
    
      var circle=$('<div class="circle"></div>');
          circle.css('top',e.pageY - 15);
          circle.css('left',e.pageX - 15)
          $('body').append(circle);
    })
  })
```

my goal is to have something like this (picture below)
[image]

Comment: My idea is to have a transparent overlay on top of all so that you can track the position of click relative to the overlay element. There is a question here regarding doing this with jQuery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element

Comment: If you use event listener you can get `clientX` and `clientY` and just add them to style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Enable onClick** 
Set `body` `element` to the full size of the page so the `onClick` is received. Add a `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` to the `body`. *If this handled by appending content to the body, this step can be skipped.*

**Moveable Blue Circle** 
In order to move the cursor on the screen you need to create a singular DOM element, then move it during the `onclick` event. This is achieved by creating a circle outside of the `onclick` and updating the CSS properties inside the `onclick`.

**Add White Box** 
As for the white box container, you can use the same code as for the circle; just offset the `top` and `left` css styling.

**Example**

```js
$(function(){
  
    // Create a new circle once.
    var circle=$('<div class="circle"></div>');
    var container=$('<div class="container"></div>');
    
    // Retrieve the body and add on click parameter.
    var body = $('body');
    body.append(circle);
    body.append(container);
    body.click(function(e){
    
          // Move circle here.
          circle.css('top', e.pageY - 15);
          circle.css('left', e.pageX - 15)
          if (circle.css('display') == 'none')
            circle.css('display', 'block');
          
          // Move container here.
          container.css('top', e.pageY + 20);
          container.css('left', e.pageX - 15);
          if (container.css('display') == 'none') {
            container.css('display', 'block');
            container.click(function(e) {
              e.stopPropagation(); // Prevents moving circle when clicking on the container.
            })
          }
    })
  })
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.circle {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.container {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great answer, but there will be a form inside the white div. How can I disable the onClick event inside the white div ? (sorry I should've added this detail in the question)

Because now I cannot click on the white div

Comment: `event.stopPropagation();` is a possibility. [Here is a example on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369080/14578434)

Comment: How would be the same answer in Vanilla JS ?

Comment: What is the purpose of (let x = e.clientX; let y = e.clientY) ? I don't see the variables x and y being used anywhere ?

Comment: I removed the unused variables from my snippet. I must have accidentally left them there after playing with your provided example.

Comment: For VanillaJS, read: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

Comment: Great thanks, I actually managed to convert your answer into vanilla js, and it's working great. My only problem now is the event propagating to the white div.

I want to be able to click on the inside of a div, like buttons and inputs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225377/discussion-between-matthew-r-dangle-and-azicode).