# Calculate clicked offset of a image

Tags: javascript, css, image, offset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting the X/Y coordinates of a mouse click on an image with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159044/getting-the-x-y-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-an-image-with-jquery)

I want to calculate clicked position of a image, lets say this will be an example:

[image]

And if I would click on it somewhere, I want to display an alert with the X/Y position of the clicked area on the image, there are pixels on the images, so it should display x pixel offset and y pixel offset.

Is that possible to do with the Javascript? Any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery, use the pageX and pageY values of the event to which you substract to the offset of the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/D63KS/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').mousedown(function(e){
        var offset = {
            x: e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
            y: e.pageY - $(this).offset().top
        }
            $('#info').html('{'+offset.x+'; '+offset.y+'}');
    });
});​
```

Comment: You might want to use a valid image.

Comment: A valid image ? I used the one from his question.

Comment: Well this is strange: I didn't click his image before and went right to your fiddle. It showed me a 'broken image', even though I can see his link. Sorry for the comment then, my bad.

Comment: @BaliBalo Works fine, but is that possible to make one pixel dimension to be 2 width / 2 height instead if 1/1 and then calculate it?

Comment: @Scott Sure, just divide by 2 the values. x: (e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / 2

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get x and y, where 'theimage' is the id of your image

```
$("#theimage").live("click",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    var y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;


});
```