# How to get correct position of the mouse click event on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I have a canvas:

```
Canvas = function(){ //v1.0
  var o = this;
  (o.penPos = {x: 0, y: 0}, 
   o.pixelSize = 10, 
   o.pen = {style: "solid", size: 1, color: "#000"}, 
   o.brush = {style: "solid", color: "#000"});
};
```

I am doing the following on click event:

```
document.onclick = function(e){
  canvas.pixel(e.x, e.y);
}
```

but it doesn't show the co ordinates in correct position, I don't know what is going wrong, as I am new to UI designing.

Comment: You also need to use the formatting options of SO properly. It was a right mess

Comment: where is your `canvas.pixel` code? your code is missing something.

Comment: You could use code from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2159129/816449

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to listen for clicks on `document` you want:

```
event.offsetX 
event.offsetY
```

To get the coordinates relative to the canvas element.  You will also need to check that your target element is the canvas element of interest.

You may be better off listening for clicks on the canvas element itself.