# Show an animation on click location

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouse

I have a div containing an image. When the user clicks on the image the x,y coordinates of the mouse are saved.

I would like to add an effect so that the user can see where he/she clicked. I.e. if the user clicks in the middle of the image a marker or an animation should be placed there, but if he/she clicks somewhere else that marker should be removed and displayed at the new click location.

I have honestly looked everywhere for a solution / answer to this. As requested here is the code used for the coordinate function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function FindPosition(oElement)
{
  if(typeof( oElement.offsetParent ) != "undefined")
  {
    for(var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent)
    {
      posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
      posY += oElement.offsetTop;
    }
      return [ posX, posY ];
    }
    else
    {
      return [ oElement.x, oElement.y ];
    }
}

function GetCoordinates(e)
{
  var PosX = 0;
  var PosY = 0;
  var ImgPos;
  ImgPos = FindPosition(myImg);
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  if (e.pageX || e.pageY)
  {
    PosX = e.pageX;
    PosY = e.pageY;
  }
  else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)
    {
      PosX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
        + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      PosY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
        + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
  PosX = PosX - ImgPos[0];
  PosY = PosY - ImgPos[1];
 // document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = PosX;
 // document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = PosY;
  document.getElementById("xtextinput").value = PosX;
  document.getElementById("ytextinput").value = PosY;
}

//-->
</script>
<th width="53%" height="auto" class="settingsrow" style="border-bottom: hidden; cursor:crosshair;" scope="row">
<img id="myImgId" alt="" src="../floorplanimages/<?php echo ($floorplan['floorplanimage']) ?>" width="650" height="951" />
</th>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var myImg = document.getElementById("myImgId");
myImg.onmousedown = GetCoordinates;
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code of what you've got so far?

Comment: What exactly is the problem/your question? How to set an element to a specific location? How to dynamically load e.g. an img?

Comment: Kingkero: Yes, how to place an image at the click location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up coding:

```
<img src="../icons/location_marker_green.png" id="marker" style="display: ; position: absolute;" />
    <img src="background" id="myImgId" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myImgId').click(function(e)
    {
       $('#markeranim').css('left', e.pageX).css('top', e.pageY).show();
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a div element which initially is set to hide() and whose z-index is greater den the image containing element. Use pageX and pageY to position that div element dynamically on click, and then use show() method for that element.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159044/getting-the-x-y-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-an-image-with-jquery) to see how to retrieve x,y coordinates with jQuery.

Once you get the coordinates, you write a function to do whatever you want with the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

This is my very simple and perfect solution, write you comment please... all of explanations, in the comments...

In your script:

```js
document.getElementById('logo-touched').style.animationName = 'logo-button-fade-value';
```

In your html:

```html
<button id="logo-touched" class="logo-button logo-button-animation" type="button" onclick="logoButtonFadeOut()">

// explanations...
.logo-button-animation {
  animationName: logo-button-fade-value;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  /* animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) */
}
@keyframes logo-button-fade-value {
  1% {
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
        
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
        
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
        
function logoButtonFadeOut() {
  //animationName is the property in the style 
  //logo-button-fade-value is the value in the style
  //logo-button-fade-value is the animation-name 
  //@keyframes (logo-button-fade-value)
  //.style.animationName = 'logo-button-fade-value'; = animation-name: logo-button-fade-value; (in the .logo-button-animation style)
  document.getElementById('logo-touched').style.animationName = 'logo-button-fade-value';
}
```