# JS - Is it possible to get the exact width of the element where it clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, progress-bar

For a progress bar of music, like youtube progress bar.
I just want use this with a JS/JQuery.

For example, if I had this code:

```
<div style="pointer:cursor;width:250px;background:#cccccc">&nbsp;</div>
```

and lets say I click exact on the half of this div element,I want that JS returns 125px.Is there any way to do so?

Comment: This should help you:
[getting the X/Y coordinates of a mouse click][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159044/getting-the-x-y-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-an-image-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
$('div').on('click',function(e){
    console.log(e.clientX - this.offsetLeft);
});
```