# Mouse click coordinates relative to the parent div's top left corner

Tags: javascript, html

How to get mouse click coordinates **relative to the parent div's top left corner** instead of top left corner of the browser's viewport ?

---

**Example** : If you click on `#mydiv` in the code below, how to get the coordinates relative to `#mydiv`'s top left corner?

```js
mydiv.onclick = function(e) { alert(e.clientX + ' ' + e.clientY); }
```

```css
#blah { position: absolute; top:50px; left:60px; width: 1000px; height: 1000px; background-color: #F0F }

#mydiv { position: absolute; top:100px; left:100px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #FF0 }
```

```html
<div id="blah"><div id="mydiv">Blah</div></div>
```

*Edited (there was a major mistake in the example).*

Comment: figure out the element's offset, then it's simple math.

Comment: @MarcB yes but do we have to walk recursively all the parent, grand-parent, grand-grand-parent `div` and add their offset? Would this be a really clean solution?

Comment: Please provide your fiddle ???

Comment: @AshishMishra I posted a StackOverflow code snippet, it's similar to a jsfiddle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159044/getting-the-x-y-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-an-image-with-jquery

Comment: Means you want to get top left corner of #blah element ?? when you click inside #mydiv...right ??

Comment: @Basj: the other option is the browser/js engine waste a ton of cpu cycles recalculating offsets for all elements on every dom change.

Comment: Oh you're right @AshishMishra, I did a mistake in the question. Corrected now: `if you click on #mydiv in the code below, how to get the coordinates relative to #mydiv's top left corner? `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is my code, sorry for using JQuery : but it gives the coordinates of parent element relative to `#mydiv`.

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', function(e) { 
    var offs = $('#mydiv').offset();
    alert((e.clientX - offs.left) + ' ' + (e.clientY - offs.top)); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
mydiv.onclick = function(e) { 
    var offsets =element_offsets(this.parentNode);
    alert(e.clientX-offsets.left);
    alert(e.clientY-offsets.top);
}


function element_offsets(e) {
    var left = 0, top = 0;
    do {
        left += e.offsetLeft;
        top += e.offsetTop;
    } while (e = e.offsetParent);
    return { left: left, top: top };
}
```

Comment: It does not work (you can try in my example) because it does not add each offset of each parent / grandparent / grandgrandparent div

Comment: Ah ok, I did not know it could have grandparents. I fixed the answer to add each offset.

Answer (score 0):

See the script and example from this page:

http://coursesweb.net/javascript/get-mouse-coordinates-inside-div-image_s2

Comment: I think this doesn't work if there is a `div` with offset inside another `div`  with offset : we should sum all the offsets, don't we?