# How to capture coordinates of image using jsp and servlet?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I want to generate a function where I upload a picture and when I **click** on the image, the **x, y coordinates** of the point I clicked will be **captured** and **stored** inside MySQL database.

Anyone can suggest how to do it ?

Comment: You are facing problems with which part exactly ?

Comment: the function code that will capture the coordinates when I click on the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to capture co-ordinates and store in database, you need to

1. Take the co-ordinates (x and y) using JavaScript.
2. Send the co-ordinates to JSP or Servlet using [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) .
3. Store the values in database as usual way.

## 1. Using JavaScript to capture the co-ordinates.

To determine the exact x and y coordinates of a mouse event, use the following properties:

1. event.screenX, event.screenY (the screen x and y coordinates).
2. event.clientX, event.clientY (coordinates relative to the top left corner of the browser window or frame).

Here is the source code of the onclick event handler used in this example:

```
  //Function to call on Onclick Event 
  var a = document.getElementById('image_id');
  a.addEventListener('click',handleEvent); 

  //function to capture the co-ordinates
  function handleEvent(e){
  var evt = e ? e:window.event;
  var clickX=0, clickY=0;

  if ((evt.clientX || evt.clientY) &&
  document.body &&
  document.body.scrollLeft!=null) {
    clickX = evt.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
    clickY = evt.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
  }

  if ((evt.clientX || evt.clientY) &&
  document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' && 
  document.documentElement && 
  document.documentElement.scrollLeft!=null) {
   clickX = evt.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
   clickY = evt.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
  if (evt.pageX || evt.pageY) {
   clickX = evt.pageX;
   clickY = evt.pageY;
  }

  alert (evt.type.toUpperCase() + ' mouse event:'
   +'\n pageX = ' + clickX
   +'\n pageY = ' + clickY 
   +'\n clientX = ' + evt.clientX
   +'\n clientY = '  + evt.clientY 
   +'\n screenX = ' + evt.screenX 
   +'\n screenY = ' + evt.screenY
  )
   sendInfo(evt.clientX,evt.clientY); 
   return false;
 }
```

## 2. Send the co-ordinates to JSP or Servlet using AJAX

Code:

```
  function sendInfo(x,y)  
  {  

   var url="jspName.jsp?valX="+x+"&valY="+y;  

   if(window.XMLHttpRequest){  
   request=new XMLHttpRequest();  
  }  
  else if(window.ActiveXObject){  
   request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
  }  

  try  
  {  
   request.onreadystatechange=getInfo;  
   request.open("GET",url,true);  
   request.send();  
  }  
  catch(e)  
  {  
   alert("Unable to connect to server");  
  }  
 }  

 function getInfo(){  
  if(request.readyState==4){  
  var val=request.responseText;  
  alert("Succesful !! responseText is :"+val)
  }else{
   alert("Problem !!");
  }  
 }
```

## 3. Store the values in database from jspName.jsp.

This is the easy part.

Reference:  [Insert record into database](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-insert-records.htm)

Comment: Points 1) and 2) are much easier (i.e. require less code to write) if one uses jQuery: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159044/getting-the-x-y-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-an-image-with-jquery 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get

Comment: A few comments and a working fiddle would make is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

By far the most easiest method is using plain old `<input type="image" src="...">`. When clicking on it, [browser will send the coordinates](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.image.html).

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>
        Clicking the following image will submit the form with 
        additional `x` and `y` parameters.
    </p>
    <input type="image" src="uploaded-image.png">
</form>
```

Comment: It will work only on form submission, which will force the page to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

If capturing the `(X, Y)` is your only problem, then the following function will help you.

```
function getXY(event) {
    var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;             // get the relative X
    var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;             // get the relative Y
    alert('(' + x + ',' + y + ')');
    // Use AJAX to send data to server.
}
```

Check out this [fiddle (Live Demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/51ddqr89/2/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
function getXY(event) {
  var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft; // get the relative X
  var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop; // get the relative Y
  alert('(' + x + ',' + y + ')');
  // Use AJAX to send data to server.
}

//register onclick listener
document.getElementById('image').addEventListener('click', getXY);
```

```html
<img id='image' src='http://www.pinaldave.com/bimg/ilovesamples.jpg' />
```