# calculate positioning of image to follow scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I want to draw a line on screen from the top of the page to the bottom when the user scrolls the page and have an arrow at the bottom of it. I don't want to use fixed position so that its always in the same spot, I want it to indicate where they are on the page by determining the page length etc.

I have the following code that works to a point. The problem with this is the arrow disappears off the bottom of the page when I scroll just after half way down.

I have tried different variations of this code but none work. Can anyone help?

```
//Draw dotted line on scroll - works to certain extent but scrolls off page
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        if ( $.windowScrollTop() > 10 ) {
            var pos = $.windowScrollTop();
            var scrollHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
            var element = $('#dashes');
            $( '#line' ).css( 'height', pos - scrollHeight / 4 );
            $( '#arrow' ).css( 'top', pos - scrollHeight / 4 );
        } else {
            $( '#line' ).css( 'height', '6px' );
            $( '#arrow' ).css( 'top', '-150px' );
        }
    });

//also tried the below

    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
        var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
        if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
            // when scroll to bottom of the page
            alert('bottom');
        } else {
                $( '#line' ).css( 'height', $(window).scrollTop() );
                $( '#arrow' ).css( 'top', $(window).scrollTop() );      
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111425/calculate-position-of-a-point-on-image-in-percentage

Comment: Ok so this uses $(this).offset(); but not sure how to apply that to my code

Comment: Can you post your markup/css or create a simplified example so we can play around with it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What we are trying to do here is reflect the document height into an element of window height. So the actual scrollable document height will be

```
    var actualScrollHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    /* This is the distance we actually scroll */
```

And our `#line` will have a maximum possible height of

```
    var lineMaxHeight = $(window).height() - topMargin - bottomMargin - arrowHeight;
    /* #arrow is inside #line but we positioned it outside it's height */
```

No to reflect the scroll progress in `#line` elements height what we need to do is

```
    var lineHeight = $(document).scrollTop() / actualScrollHeight * lineMaxHeight;
    /* Super Easy, isn't it? */
```

**The Final Result:**

You don't need to position both the `#line` and `#arrow`. Fix the `#arrow` at the bottom of `#line` and then just changing the height of `#line` works just fine. I added the `topMargin` and `bottomMargin` feature making screen adjustment more customizing.

```js
$(function(){
  var topMargin = 15, bottomMargin = 5;
  var arrowHeight = $('#arrow').height();
  var $lineElement = $('#line');
  $lineElement.height(topMargin);
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var actualScrollHeight = $(document).height() - winHeight;
    var lineMaxHeight = winHeight - topMargin - bottomMargin - arrowHeight;
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    var lineHeight = scrollTop / actualScrollHeight * lineMaxHeight;
    $lineElement.height(topMargin + lineHeight);
  });
});
```

```css
#logo {
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #53befd;
  padding: 20px;
}

#line {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAMCAYAAABBV8wuAAAAFklEQVR42mNgoB74OEXzPzY8sBLUAwB6PmBV1D+CIAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 19px;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 3px;
}

#arrow {
  background-color: #f28323;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  left: -18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo">LOGO </div>
<p>  Page content go here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here</p><p>  Page content go here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here</p><p>  Page content go here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here</p><p>  Page content go here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here</p><p>  Page content go here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here</p><p>  Page content go here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here</p><p>  Page content go here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here</p><p>  Page content go here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here</p><p>  Page content go here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here</p><p>  Page content go here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here<br /> and here</p>
<div id="line"><div id="arrow">V</div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approaches look like you're overthinking it. I'm seeing an HTML `progress` element turned 180 degrees for the visual. Then, set it's `value` attribute dynamically with JS as the user scrolls and the line will essentially look like it's animating down.

```
// PROGRESS INDICATOR
// Calculate height of main object and the window, set max attr of progress accordingly
var winHeight = $(window).height(),
    sectionHeight = $('#line').height(),
    progressBar = $('progress'),
    max,
    value;

// Set the maximum scrollable area
max = sectionHeight - winHeight;
progressBar.attr('max', sectionHeight);

// Set value attr of progress, changes as user scrolls
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
  value = $(window).scrollTop();
  progressBar.attr('value', value);
});
```

CSS for the progress element would look something like this, where you place the bar as a fixed element on the page and animate it to cover progressively more of the page with the JS above.

CSS example:

```
progress {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none; //firefox fix
  color: green;
  height: 2.5rem;
  margin-top: 20vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 8rem;
  width: 100vh;

  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(1800%);
  }

  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(1200%); // matches content shift to smaller column
  }
}
```

I built [this on one of my client sites](https://emp.nacubo.org/mission/) if you want to see if working in the wild (only works at about 1000px and higher so make sure your window is wide enough).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easier solution with less code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var p = ($('body').height() - $(window).height()) / ($(window).height() - 43);
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop() / p;
    $(':root').css('--scroll-top', scrollTop + 43 + "px");
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --scroll-top: 43px;
}

#logo {
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #53befd;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  height: 210vh;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

#line:before {
  content: "V";
  background-color: #f28323;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#line {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: var(--scroll-top);
  width: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f28323 50%, transparent 50%) 50% 0/3px 12px repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo">LOGO </div>
<div class="content"></div>

<div id="line"></div>
```