# jQuery ignore transparent areas of images

Tags: jquery, canvas

I want to make something to what has been done here:

http://www.cw-internetdienste.de/pixelselection/

However, it doesn't work if I just copy the pixelSelection.js file from this site. I would really like to make my own, not just something somebody else wrote, but am clueless how to do it.

I've tried .svg and image mapping together, but even if I image map I can't hover the background image within the foreground transparent area, and it's really difficult to map every image in detail.

Comment: FWICT, the code on this page should work elsewhere ... do you have an example of it not working on your own site?

Comment: Sure: http://emilmoe.dk/ - I must have misunderstood a detail somewhere

Comment: Well, the `pixelselection` page doesn't work for me. I always get `undefined clicked!` so the problem may not be your implementation, but the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya the old version of my script was kinda buggy, I recently updated it with a much more configurable and cleaner jquery plugin version. I also published it on github.

http://www.cw-internetdienste.de/pixelselection/

Maybe the new version might help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041399/how-to-use-javascript-or-jquery-to-read-a-pixel-of-an-image) in order to get the RGBA values for a pixel of an image using JavaScript, I'll call this:

```
isTransparrent(imageUrl, x, y);
```

Then whenever you hover over an image you can check using that function:

```
$('#some-image').hover(function(e) {
    var isTrans = isTransparent(
        this.src,
        e.pageX - $(this).pageX, // relative x position in image
        e.pageY - $(this).pageY  // relative y position in image
    );
    console.log(isTrans ? 'transparent pixel', 'not transparent pixel');
});
```