# Pixel Color Values of image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image

Hi wanted to get the list of pixel color values(RBG) from an image using Javascript so that i can get interesting colors from an image .can anyone help me on this issue please...

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript eyedropper (tell colour of Pixel under mouse cursor)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936021/javascript-eyedropper-tell-colour-of-pixel-under-mouse-cursor)

Comment: Marking as a duplicate because the accepted answer deals with getting the colour value from an image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use javascript or jQuery to read a pixel of an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041399/how-to-use-javascript-or-jquery-to-read-a-pixel-of-an-image)

Answer (score 2):

try to create canvas element, draw image on i and then use array of pixeldata from it:

```
data = canvas.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
```

it gives you array with RGBA colors

Comment: In this case, how can you copy the image data to the canvas? Also, how can you "draw image on i"?

Comment: Also, is it possible to draw an image from a file onto a canvas, and then get the pixel data from the image?