# Is there a way to read an image pixel by pixel and return each pixel's color into an array indexed by its coordinates?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, coordinates, pixel

I'm trying to use a pixel map i made for a coordinate system in a browser game I'm making. Each color represents a terrain type with associated values that impact various aspects of the game.

So the question: is there a way with PHP or JavaScript to "read" an 
image pixel by pixel and then return the color value of each pixel in an array for storage in a database so that i can quickly append each color to my own x,y coordinates based from the center of the image and not the corner?

Comment: Up right there's search box... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735470/get-pixel-color-from-canvas-on-mouseover, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511509/pixel-color-values-of-image-using-javascript

Comment: In addition to that, there's a function in PHP called [`imagecolorat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php).

Comment: also the html5 `<canvas>` element should have that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For a javascript-based game, I'd recommend hard-coding an array client-side and storing only IMPORTANT coordinates in there to reduce the size of the array so you don't have to check it as often. Then switch to a bitmap/bitboard representation much like how most modern chess engines function today. Then have a bitmap for each possible block type e.g. wall, empty, stairs, etc. The concept of a bitmap is to map the coordinates of the pieces of interest. Pieces on the map are given a boolean true value while unmapped coordinates will have a boolean false value. Then repeat this process for each block type.

e.g.

```
walls:[[3,-7],[-8,9],[30,67],[31,67],[32,68]]
ustairs:[[4,6],[7,8],[8,9]]
dstairs:[[7,6],[-2,-4],[-7,-9]]
```

Even if you decide not to switch to a bitmap/bitboard representation, at least have mercy on your database backend if you wind-up storing all the coordinates there.

You could use PHP's `imagecolorat()` function to populate your database but I would vote against using this function at runtime everytime you need to check a coordinate.
This function works well with non-indexed images such as PNGs.

But if you open up an indexed image in PHP such as a GIF, then you will have to look up the color for the index used in the image before getting its color value. Thus you would use `imagecolorsforindex()`. Edit: Sorry I mean `imagecolorexact()`