# Is there a js library can can generate a color palette from an image?

Tags: javascript, colors, styles

Something that might do something like

```
<img  class="image" ... />

$(".image").get_colors()
```

I know there are few websites where you can upload your image and it would generate the color for you but I want something to put on my website

Something like [this](http://designshack.net/gallery) where you see the colors generated from the screenshot and can search by colors. I tried to check the source code but I could not see any reference to a js library.

I need this feature to work with js if possible.

**EDIT:**
The image would be on the page already; I just need to generate its color, so I don't want the uploading features.

Thanks.

Comment: No No, no uploading. Just get the color off an image in the page

Comment: Just draw the image on a canvas element and check by your self. Don't know what you expect as return of `get_colors`.

Comment: Haven't used canvas before (I reacently started looking at html5) so Im going to give it a try - Do you know any resource that might cover the effect you are talking about @Prusse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be interested in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205955/algorithm-or-library-for-color-quantization-reduced-image-color-palette-in-javas) and [my answer to another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819447/javascript-image-main-cluster-color/6819953#6819953).

Getting *all* the colors from an image is simple, at least in a browser that supports the `canvas` element - the technique is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041399/how-to-use-javascript-or-jquery-to-read-a-pixel-of-an-image). You end up with a `CanvasPixelArray` ([described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)), which is essentially an array like `[r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a, ...]` where `r,g,b,a` are bytes indicating the red, green, blue, and alpha values of each pixel.

The hard part is identifying or creating a small selection of representative colors, rather than the 10,000 colors that might be in a 100x100 image. This is a pretty complicated problem, with many solutions ([overview here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization)). You can see Javascript implementations of two possible algorithms in the [clusterfck library](http://harthur.github.com/clusterfck/) and [my port of the Leptonica Modified Median Cut algorithm](https://gist.github.com/1104622).

Comment: This is the only professional answer to this question. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 2):

I did write just for fun. It is a jquery plugin, if you don't use it you can read it for some pointers. If there is some error during the call to `get_colors` a array is set in the return value to hold the errors, it returns an array of objects, these objects are a histogram of a image(one item in the array for every selected element).

```
(function($, window, document, undefined){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    if (canvas && canvas.getContext){
        $.fn.get_colors = function(){
            var rv = [];
            this.each(function(){
                var tagname = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
                if ((tagname === 'img') || (tagname === 'canvas') || (tagname === 'video')){
                    //something bad can happend when drawing the image
                    try{
                        var w = this.getAttribute('width');
                        var h = this.getAttribute('height');
                        canvas.setAttribute('width', w);  
                        canvas.setAttribute('height', h); 
                        var ctxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        if (ctxt){
                            ctxt.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                            var imagedata = ctxt.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
                            var data = imagedata.data;
                            //log('imagedata.width:'+imagedata.width+' imagedata.height:'+imagedata.height+' w:'+w+' h:'+h);
                            var obj = {};
                            var color = '';
                            var r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0;
                            var pix = data.length;
                            for (pix--; pix > 2; pix-=4){
                                //a = data[pix - 0];
                                b = data[pix - 1];
                                g = data[pix - 2];
                                r = data[pix - 3];
                                if (r < 16) r = '0' + r.toString(16);
                                else r = r.toString(16);
                                if (g < 16) g = '0' + g.toString(16);
                                else g = g.toString(16);
                                if (b < 16) b = '0' + b.toString(16);
                                else b = b.toString(16);
                                //if (a < 16) a = '0' + r.toString(16);
                                //else a = a.toString(16);
                                //color = r + g + b + a;
                                color = r + g + b;
                                if (obj[color] > 0) ++obj[color];
                                else obj[color] = 1;
                            }
                            rv.push(obj);
                            imagedata = data = obj = null;
                        }
                        ctxt = null;
                    } catch(error){
                        if (!rv.errors){
                            rv.errors = [];
                        }
                        rv.errors.push(error);
                    }
                }
            });
            return rv;
        };
    } else{
        $.fn.get_colors = function(){
            throw new Error('canvas element support required!');
        };
    }
})(jQuery, this, this.document);
```

If a document with only one image with 4 pixels(2x2) "#ff0000, #00ff00, #0000ff, #ff0000", if you do `$('img').get_colors();` it returns `[{"ff0000": 2, "0000ff": 1, "00ff00":1}]`.

To learn how to use the canvas element you could look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial) and at the [specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#pixel-manipulation) in development for details about pixel manipulation.

Edit: commented out a line I was using when debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this project on Github?

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/

It's a javascript solution. (It depends on two additional libraries: jquery, quantize.js).

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
colorThief.getPalette(sourceImage, 8);
getPalette(sourceImage[, colorCount, quality])
```

Which will return an array, like so: [ [num, num, num], [num, num, num], ... ]