# Converting xyz data to a 3D image that can be rotated and zoomed by a site visitor

Tags: java, 3d, terrain

I have been trying to find a way to do this for 4-5 weeks. I'm willing to learn anything I need to. I've mostly been trying in Java but doesn't need to be.

Here are the specifics. I am trying to create a 3D image of inland lakes. I scan the lakes with a high end sonar. It allows me to export a csv file (that eventually I will put in a database) with lat, long, depth, time stamp, and maybe a couple of other things.

I want to take that "x, y, z" data (and time stamp if needed), turn it into a 3D image of the lake and put it on a webpage for user. I want the user to be able to rotate and zoom the image. Color for different depth, contour lines, etc... I'll figure out later if needed.

I'm assuming somebody does this for mountains with lidar or something but I can't find it anywhere!

Any help is appreciated. If it's not a complete answer that is fine. I'm looking for anything!

Comment: What you need is a good visualization library in Java. Have you tried to google for some??

Comment: Well, I have worked ploting 3D charts [using Java 3D library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_3D). Maybe, you can work with a Java Applet with Java 3D. Googling a little I have found this service: [https://sketchfab.com/](https://sketchfab.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Since your target is the web and you are willing to learn anything, you should look into WebGL (which is a Javascript-based technology). Most recent browsers support it now.

[This demo](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_terrain.html) may be similar to what you want to achieve. I got the link from [this question about heightmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7638008/309334)

I also skimmed [this post](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/10/terrain-building-with-threejs-part-1.html) and it seems like the author has an entire series on doing something like you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The longitude + latitude + altitude was taken from the GPS and it was set to a 3D "globe" model created "by hand" - from code. I think a few location of stars too. It had the functionality of rotate and zoom too. It was an Android application...

Unfortunately I don't know more. I have been searching for examples for rotation vector and at least I have checked 100+ source codes at Github + at least 100 apps from Play Store.

Try to find that one. I hope it helps a bit.