# detecting "we have no imagery" of google maps street view static images

Tags: image, google-maps, static, google-street-view

I'm generating street view static images like so:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=1080x400&location=%s&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=0&key=%s

If you visit that link you see an image that says, "Sorry, we have no imagery for this..."

Is there any way to detect this "sorry" state so that I can fall back to another image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell if Google's Streetview Image API Returns "Sorry, we have no imagery here" (ie. NULL) Result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795533/how-can-i-tell-if-googles-streetview-image-api-returns-sorry-we-have-no-image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this situation is already build in in the 3.0 version due
the boolean test status === streetviewStatus.Ok, here is a snippet from my situation solving

```
if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
            var img = document.createElement("IMG");
            img.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=160x205&location='+ lat +','+ lng  +'&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyC_OXsfB8-03ZXcslwOiN9EXSLZgwRy94s';
            var oldImg = document.getElementById('streetViewImage');
            document.getElementById('streetViewContainerShow').replaceChild(img, streetViewImage);
        } else {
            var img = document.createElement("IMG");
            img.src = '../../images/ProfilnoProfilPicture.jpg';
            img.height = 205;
            img.width = 160;
            var oldImg = document.getElementById('streetViewImage');
            document.getElementById('streetViewContainerShow').replaceChild(img, streetViewImage);
        }
```

Comment: This works partially, but be aware that the JavaScript API may return panos (pano ID near a latlng) that are not available in the Street View Image API. See code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10402 for the full details.

Answer (score 7):

One quick solution would be to load the image file using xmlrpc and check that its md5sum is `30234b543d5438e0a0614bf07f1ebd25`, or that its size is `1717` bytes (it's unlikely that another image can have exactly the same size), but that's not very robust since I have seen Google change the position of the text in the image. Though it's a very good start for a prototype.

You could go for image processing instead. Note that it's still not perfectly robust since Google could decide to change the looks of the image anytime. You'll have to decide whether it's worth it.

Anyway, here is how I would do it using jQuery:

- load the image and open a 2D context for direct pxiel access (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041399/111461) for how to do it)
- analyse the image:

  - sample groups of 2×2 pixels at random locations; I recommend at least 30 groups
  - a group of 2×2 pixels is *good* if all the pixels have the same value and their R/G/B values do not differ by more than 10% (ie. they're grey)
  - count the ratio of *good* pixel groups in the image
- if there are more than 70% *good* pixel groups, then we are pretty sure this is the “no imagery” version: replace it with another image of your choice.

The reason I do not recommend testing directly for an RGB value is because JPEG decompression may have slightly different behaviours on different browsers.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40803070/1069142 for a more reliable method that just became available.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2016, you can use the new [**Street View Image Metadata API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata).

Now you just need the [`status`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata#status-codes) field to know if a panorama is found.

*Example requests:*

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?size=600x300&location=78.648401,14.194336&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&key=YOUR_API_KEY

```
{
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?size=600x300&location=eiffel%20tower,%20paris,%20france&heading=-45&pitch=42&fov=110&key=YOUR_API_KEY

```
{
   ...
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the getPanoramaByLocation function (see http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#StreetViewService).

try something like this:

```
function handleMapClick()
{
 var ll= new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
 sv.getPanoramaByLocation(ll, 50, processSVData);
}

function processSVData(data, status) {
 if (status==google.maps.StreetViewStatus.ZERO_RESULTS)
 {
   <DO SOMETHING>
 }
}
```

Comment: This works partially, but be aware that the JavaScript API may return panos (pano ID near a latlng) that are not available in the Street View Image API. See code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10402 for the full details.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to load the image and then compare some pixels colors.  The "no streetview" image from google is always the same.  Here is how you would compare 2 pixels:

```
var url = STREETVIEWURL
var img = new Image();
// Add some info to prevent cross origin tainting
img.src = url + '?' + new Date().getTime();
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.onload = function() {
    var context = document.createElement('CANVAS').getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    //load 2 pixels.  I chose the first one and the 5th row
    var data1 = context.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
    var data2 = context.getImageData(0, 5, 1, 1).data;
    console.log(data1);
    // google unknown image is this pixel color [228,227,223,255]
    if(data1[0]==228 && data1[1]==227 && data1[2]==223 && data1[3]==255 && 
                     data2[0]==228 && data2[1]==227 && data2[2]==223 && data2[3]==255){
        console.log("NO StreetView Available");
    }else{
         console.log("StreetView is Available");
    }
};
```

Some potential issues:
I've seen some errors with CrossOrigin tainting.  Also, if google changes the image returned this code will break.

Answer (score 0):

Request a google street view image and if it has a specific file size it is a 'Not street view avaible'. I did the follwing:

```
var url = 'google street view url';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    try {
      var image = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'image/jpeg'});

      if (image.size) {
        if (url.indexOf('640x640') > -1 && image.size === 8410) {
          // Not street view
        }

        if (url.indexOf('400x300') > -1 && image.size === 3946) {
           // Not street view
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // IE 9 doesn't support blob
    }
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: nice research, but this would always be one image alteration from breaking.