# Python: how to check whether Google street view API returns no image or the API key is expired?

Tags: python, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I want to use [Google Street View API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/) to download some images in python.

Sometimes there is no image return in one area, but the API key can be **used**.

[image]

Other time API key is **expired** or **invalid**, and also cannot return image.

```
The Google Maps API server rejected your request. The provided API key is expired.
```

How to distinguish these two situations with code in Python?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to make an api call with the `requests` library, and parse the JSON response:

```
import requests
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=46.414382,10.013988&heading=151.78&pitch=-0.76&key=YOUR_API_KEY'

r = requests.get(url)
results = r.json()
error_message = results.get('error_message')
```

Now `error_message` will be the text of the error message (e.g., `'The provided API key is expired.'`), or will be `None` if there is no error message. So later in your code you can check if there is an error message, and do things based on the content of the message:

```
if error_message and 'The provided API key is invalid.' in error_message:
    do_something()
elif ...:
    do_something_else()
```

You could also check the key `'status'` if you just want to see if the request was successful or not:

```
status = results.get('status')
```

Comment: how to check whether there is image in the region?

Comment: @karl_TUM I assume it that case that `results.get('status')` will return the string `'ZERO_RESULTS'`, but you would have to test. If that doesn't work, check the documentation, and if you still can't figure it out, ask a new question on this site. Good luck!

Comment: Nope, what won't work. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40803070/1069142 for the recipe to find whether there is a Street View panorama at given locations.