# How do I morph / animate a custom shape into a circle? CANVAS JS

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I have a slice/segment of a circle and want to animate it morphing into a new complete circle with a 'biological' feel to it.
By biological I mean a way other than increasing the arc-length of the segment.

How can I get the kind of animation you would get if tweening a square to a circle in Flash, but in Canvas JS?

Comment: A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219266/jquery-morphing-image-effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you heard of the Raphael JavaScript library? Here's an example. I think this demonstrates exactly what you described.

http://raphaeljs.com/animation.html