# Passing uploaded image through webrtc - pubnub

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, pubnub

I am trying to implement a web site where people will be able through html5 canvas and pubnub to draw and everyone see the other's drawing. So far everything is good, the only thing is that i want people to be able to upload images and then draw on them (of course everyone will be able to see the uploaded images).
 From this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906734/how-to-upload-image-into-html5-canvas) i took the part of the image upload, but when i upload the image it doesn't happen on the other users. Any ideas on how can this be implemented?

Comment: If you share a `<canvas>` then it's just a matter of drawing that image onto the canvas using `ctx.drawImage()`. You then of course need to share this with the others; i.e. tell the clients which image to draw where

Comment: Seems pretty neat thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

> Get the PubNub WebRTC SDK - https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk

### WebRTC Photo Sharing **without STUN or TURN**

You can easily snap a photo from the video stream and
send it to your friends in an instant.
You can think of this as an **Instagram WebRTC** style.
Also Photo Sharing works through Corporate Enterprise Firewalls.

#### WebRTC Camera Photo Sharing Broadcast

`phone.snap()`

> Broadcast your camera photo to all connected sessions.
>   Also get the IMG data as base64 supported format
>   for local display if desired.

```
phone.ready(function(){
    // Auto Send Camera's Photo to all connected Sessions.
    var photo = phone.snap();
    $('#photo-div').append(photo.image);
});
```

#### WebRTC Session Camera Photo Share

`session.snap()`

> Send your camera's latest frame as raw IMG to
>   a specific call session.

```
phone.ready(function(){
    var session = phone.dial('4321');
    var photo   = session.snap();
    $('#photo-div').append(photo.image);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it directly :

```
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', 640);
    canvas.setAttribute('height',400);

    function snapshot() {
    if (localStream) {
    ctx.drawImage(localVideo, 0, 0);         
    var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
    send({snap: imageData});
}
}
```

At the other end, the HTML should contain an image tag <,image id="img"><,/image>

Javascript :

```
function messageHandler(data){      // typeof(data) = 'object'
document.querySelector('img').src = data.snap; 

}
```