# How to upload a file to html canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I'm making a drawing based html website, I made a save button but I don't know how to make an upload input, can someone help?

Comment: may be a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906734/how-to-upload-image-into-html5-canvas (check it out)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload image into HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906734/how-to-upload-image-into-html5-canvas)