# JavaScript: Multiple cropping selection in one image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, jcrop, cropperjs

**PS:** Is it not a research kind of question! I have been trying to do this from very long time.

I am trying to make **web based an image editor where user can select multiple cropping area and after selection save/download all the image area.** like below.

As of now I discovered two libraries

1.**Cropper.JS** where is only single selection feature is available.

2.**Jcrop** where only single selection area restrictions.

I am **currently using cropper.Js** but it seems impossible for me to **make multiple selection cropping.**
Any help is much appreciated.if any other method/library available in JavaScript, Angular or PHP or reactJS for multiple image area selection and crop and download in one go as in the image below.

[image]

> As per @Keyhan Answer I am Updating my Jcrop library Code

```
 <div style="padding:0 5%;">
   <img id="target" src="https://d3o1694hluedf9.cloudfront.net/market-750.jpg">
 </div> 

 <button id="save">Crop it!</button>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/jcrop/dist/jcrop.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jcrop"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    <script>


    setImage();
    var jcp;
    var jcp;
    Jcrop.load('target').then(img => {
        //You can enable multiple cropping with this line:
        jcp = Jcrop.attach(img, { multi: true });
    });

    // to fix security issue when trying to convert to Data URI
    function setImage() {
        document.getElementById('target').setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        document.getElementById('target').src = 'https://d3o1694hluedf9.cloudfront.net/market-750.jpg';
    } 


    var link = document.getElementById('save');
    link.onclick = function () {
        //we check if at least one crop is available
        if (jcp.active) {
            var i = 0;
            var fullImg = document.getElementById("target");
            //we are looping cropped areas
            for (area of jcp.crops) {
                i++;
                //creating temp canvas and drawing cropped area on it
                canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.setAttribute('width', area.pos.w);
                canvas.setAttribute('height', area.pos.h);
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(fullImg, area.pos.x, area.pos.y, area.pos.w, area.pos.h, 0, 0, area.pos.w, area.pos.h);
                //creating temp link for saving/serving new image
                temp = document.createElement('a');
                temp.setAttribute('download', 'area' + i + '.jpg');
                temp.setAttribute('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg").replace("image/jpg", "image/octet-stream"));
                temp.click();
            }
        }
    };

</script>
```

Comment: `Jcrop.attach('target',{ multi: true });` From Jcrop documentation: https://jcrop.com/guide/#setting-options. And from Jcrop examples: https://jcrop.com/examples/custom-widget.html

Comment: @keyhan I have already tried this but there no any option of exporting the multiple crop image areas. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71046529/jcrop-how-to-upload-image-from-client-side-in-a-canvas) I already pasted where I am getting issue and error

Comment: You have x, y, width and height of cropped areas, so you can draw each of them on temp canvas https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp and finally save canvas to <img/> with canvas.toDataURL() and serve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to explain the code with comments:

```
var jcp;
    Jcrop.load('target').then(img => {
    //You can enable multiple cropping with this line:
    jcp = Jcrop.attach(img,{multi:true});
});
//assuming you have a button with id="save" for exporting cropped areas
var link=document.getElementById('save');
link.onclick = function(){
    //we check if at least one crop is available
    if(jcp.active){
        var i=0;
        var fullImg = document.getElementById("target");
        //we are looping cropped areas 
        for(area of jcp.crops){
            i++;
            //creating temp canvas and drawing cropped area on it
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.setAttribute('width',area.pos.w);
            canvas.setAttribute('height',area.pos.h);
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(fullImg, area.pos.x, area.pos.y, area.pos.w, area.pos.h, 0, 0, area.pos.w, area.pos.h);
            //creating temp link for saving/serving new image
            temp = document.createElement('a');
            temp.setAttribute('download', 'area'+i+'.jpg');
            temp.setAttribute('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg").replace("image/jpg", "image/octet-stream"));    
            temp.click();
        }
    }
};
```

EDIT: As you commented it would be nicer if we have local image loader, we can add a file input to our html

```
<img id="target" />
<br/>
<input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader"/><!-- add this for file picker -->
<button id="save">save</button>
```

and a function to our js to handle it

```
var jcp;
var save=document.getElementById('save');
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
var img = document.getElementById("target");
imageLoader.onchange=function handleImage(e){//handling our image picker <input>:
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
}
save.onclick = function(){
    if(jcp&&jcp.active){
        var i=0;
        for(area of jcp.crops){
            i++;
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.setAttribute('width',area.pos.w);
            canvas.setAttribute('height',area.pos.h);
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, area.pos.x, area.pos.y, area.pos.w, area.pos.h, 0, 0, area.pos.w, area.pos.h);
            temp = document.createElement('a');
            temp.setAttribute('download', 'area'+i+'.jpg');
            temp.setAttribute('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg").replace("image/jpg", "image/octet-stream"));    
            temp.click();
        }
    }
};
Jcrop.load('target').then(img => {
    jcp = Jcrop.attach(img,{multi:true});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @keyhan but I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')` I have updated my Question with code also, Error is around here `link.onclick = function ()`

Comment: Add a save button (`<a id="save">save</a>`) to your html

Comment: thank you :)! a tonn of thanks to save my day, A last doubt how can I upload image client side rather than giving img link?

Comment: something like `<input type="file">` where all this Jcrop code will work.

Comment: Its another question, you can implement it using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906734/how-to-upload-image-into-html5-canvas#answer-10906961

Comment: I understand but if it can be possible here a little pseudo code will be helpful :)

Comment: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71332030/how-to-handle-large-image-in-jcrop) can you help me in this question or any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, @keyhan was right `<input type="file">` is another question, but still, I am giving you an idea of how to implement Kayhan's code above.

```
<div>    
<input type="file" id="image-input" accept="image/*">
  <!-- img id name should be "target" as it is also using by Jcrop -->
<img id="target"></img>
</div>
```

and Now you can put below JavaScript  Code just above `setImage()`

```
  <script>
    let imgInput = document.getElementById('image-input');
    imgInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        if (e.target.files) {
            let imageFile = e.target.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.onload = function (event) {

                    var MAX_WIDTH = 1600;
                    var MAX_HEIGHT = 800;

                    var width = img.width;
                    var height = img.height;

                    // Change the resizing logic
                    if (width > height) {
                        if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                            height = height * (MAX_WIDTH / width);
                            width = MAX_WIDTH;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                            width = width * (MAX_HEIGHT / height);
                            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                        }
                    }

                    // Dynamically create a canvas element
                    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;
                    // var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                    // Actual resizing
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

                    // Show resized image in preview element
                    var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL(imageFile.type);
                    document.getElementById("target").src = dataurl;
                }
                img.src = e.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
        }
    });
</script>
```