# How to Handle Large image in Jcrop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jcrop

I am using **Jcrop to crop Images**, it is working fine with small size images, but Whenever I try to put **large image like 2080x2080 or 1600x1600 it covers all my screen**, also It **cannot be handle with CSS like width and height control in Image tag**

**Seeking Solution/Suggestion** -

1. Any method to put this image in container/div and then zoom-in/out with mouse event ?
2. Any method to handle large size image in a fix container and crop so that image maintain it's quality.

**P.s:** you can try with large image in below working example and see how it behaves with big Image.

```js
var jcp;
var save = document.getElementById('save');
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
var img = document.getElementById("target");
imageLoader.onchange = function handleImage(e) { //handling our image picker <input>:
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    img.src = event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
save.onclick = function() {
  if (jcp && jcp.active) {
    var i = 0;
    for (area of jcp.crops) {
      i++;
      canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.setAttribute('width', area.pos.w);
      canvas.setAttribute('height', area.pos.h);
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(img, area.pos.x, area.pos.y, area.pos.w, area.pos.h, 0, 0, area.pos.w, area.pos.h);
      temp = document.createElement('a');
      temp.setAttribute('download', 'area' + i + '.jpg');
      temp.setAttribute('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg").replace("image/jpg", "image/octet-stream"));
      temp.click();
    }
  }
};
Jcrop.load('target').then(img => {
  jcp = Jcrop.attach(img, {
    multi: true
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.cropapp {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 5%;
  background: lightgray;
}

.cropbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<head>

  <title>Jcrop Example</title>

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/jcrop@3.0.1/dist/jcrop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jcrop@3.0.1/dist/jcrop.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div style="width:400px; margin:10px auto; padding:10px 0; overflow:hidden;"><a style="float:right; display:block; padding:10px 15px; color:#fff; background-color:#237dbd; font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold; border-radius:5px;" id="save">Save</a>
    <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
    <!-- add this for file picker -->
  </div>
  <div>

    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;">

      Image Crop <span style="color:lightgray;"></span>
    </h1>

    <img id="target" style="background-size: cover !important;">


  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any fixed width or height value to your `<img id="target"/>`. Just calculate and apply the change ratio to areas:

```
  canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

  displayWidth=img.width;
  displayHeight=img.height;
  realWidth = img.naturalWidth;
  realHeight = img.naturalHeight;
  
  widthRatio = Math.round(realWidth/displayWidth);
  heightRatio = Math.round(realHeight/displayHeight);
  width=area.pos.w*widthRatio
  height=area.pos.h*heightRatio
  
  canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
  canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, area.pos.x*widthRatio, area.pos.y*heightRatio, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
```

and `<img width="500" id="target"/>` (or with css `#target{width:500px}`)