# How do I load the image from file chooser and get it to load on the canvas so that i can edit it using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, loadimage

I have been using a pixel editor called pixel paint and I wanted to create a button that allows me to load any image onto the canvas. Currently, I have been researching and testing multiple methods online and I am still struggling to get the image loaded in. Here is the code for the **script.js** method.

```
function showSelectedFile(){
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();

    var file = document.getElementById("inputfile");
    var name = file.value.replaceAll("\\","").replace("C:fakepath","").replace(".png","");
    document.getElementById("myText").value = name;
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    img.onload = function()
    {
        context.drawImage(img,0,0)
    }

    img.src = "/Users/angadp/Dropbox/Mac/Downloads/pixel-paint-master/" + name + ".png";
}
```

Also, in the script.js file I have tried to use

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-div")
```

but it gets the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function

In the **index.html** file the code is currently using `<div id="canvas-div"></div>`. So I am not really sure how to load the image onto the canvas that is using the div tag. Also at the beginning of the html file I am using `<input id='inputfile' type='file' accept = ".png" name='inputfile' onChange='showSelectedFile()'>` which makes the choose file button.

I also have a picture of pixel paint so that you would know what I am talking about.

[image: MENU]

Can you please provide me with some help on how to solve all these solutions. Thank you. I have also attached the hyperlink to the original pixel-paint so that you can download and test it.

[Pixel Editor Menu for you to download and test](https://github.com/Kully/pixel-paint)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload image into HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906734/how-to-upload-image-into-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

You can load image on `change` of file. Then `createObjectURL` (that's data:something;base64). Then load it on an image finally draw it on the `<canvas>`.

```js
function loadFile(event) {
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var dummy = document.getElementById('dummy');
  dummy.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

  dummy.onload = function() {

    ctx.drawImage(dummy, 0, 0, 600, 300);

    // Set line width
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50, 140);
    ctx.lineTo(150, 60);
    ctx.lineTo(250, 140);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();

    // free memory
    URL.revokeObjectURL(dummy.src)
    dummy.parentNode.removeChild(dummy)
  }
};
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)">
<canvas></canvas>

<img id="dummy" />
```