# event.offsetX in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, events, firefox, html5-canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script language="javascript">
function main(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var x = e.offsetX;
        var y = e.offsetY;

        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="main();">
<div style="width: 800px; height: 600px; -webkit-transform: scale(0.75,0.75); -moz-transform: scale(0.75,0.75)">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400px" height="400px" style="background-color: #cccccc;"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please consider the above quick and dirty example.
Please notice that my canvas is contained by a div having a scale transform applied.
The above code works perfectly on any webkit based browser. While moving the mouse it draws points on the canvas.
Unfortunately it doesn't in Firefox as its event model does not support the offsetX / Y properties.
How can I transform mouse coordinates from (perhaps) event.clientX (which is supported in firefox too) into canvas relative coordinates taking into account canvas position, transform etc?
Thanks, Luca.

Comment: Thankfully, Firefox 40 supports offsetX!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try layerX, layerY

```
var x = (e.offsetX === undefined) ? e.layerX : e.offsetX;
var y = (e.offsetY === undefined) ? e.layerY : e.offsetY;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Pnx4D/)

Comment: Unfortunately, Firefox layerX and layerY properties are differs from ones in other browsers. There are relative top-left corner of page, but not elemenet.

Comment: false, they are relative to the closest offsetParent including the element itself, just add "position:relative" to the element you want to use for coordenates.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but this worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704686/html5-with-jquery-e-offsetx-is-undefined-in-firefox

Comment: Didn't work on FF 32.0.3 . layerX and layerY are absent from event.

Comment: @Musa can you ammend this answer to note that `position:relative` is necessary to force these properties to be relative to the element, rather than an ancestor?

Comment: layerX and offsetX are not the same, if the target is an inline element, the offset give the position of the cursor in the element, but return a layerX relative to his non-inline parent container.

Comment: @cristiano2lopes if you are using jQuery, you may you have to use ```event.originalEvent.layerX```.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerX "This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."

Answer (score 78):

From a [JQuery bug tracker page](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8523#comment:14) - a nice polyfill is this:

```
var offX  = (e.offsetX || e.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left);
```

.. where e is the event returned from a jquery event. Obviously, only if you've got Jquery already on your project, otherwise will have to do the `offset()` stuff manually.

Comment: wow. from all answers, only this one working for me. i've tried this with absolutely positioned element, thank you man so much! best answer in this topic

Comment: var eoffsetX = (e.offsetX || e.clientX - $(e.target).offset().left + window.pageXOffset ),
    eoffsetY = (e.offsetY || e.clientY - $(e.target).offset().top + window.pageYOffset );

this fix will help if you have scrolled the page

Comment: Thanks @Denis, your answer of adding `y position` really helped me in fixing my issue

Comment: Bug tracker page has changed since the answer. It says you should use `e.pageX` instead of `e.clientX`. It fixes the problem with scrolled page, too. Works in latest Chrome, FF, and IE.

Comment: Seems that FF, since version 39, now supports this property. Good news!

Answer (score 21):

Unfortunately no solution worked for me.

I found a good implementation [here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/mouse-position/):

```
var target  = e.target || e.srcElement,
              rect    = target.getBoundingClientRect(),
              offsetX = e.clientX - rect.left,
              offsetY  = e.clientY - rect.top;

e.offsetX   = offsetX;
e.offsetY   = offsetY;
```

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately offsetX and layerX are not exactly the same as offsetX is the offset within the current element but layerX is the offset from the page. Below is a fix I am currently using for this:

```
function fixEvent(e) {
    if (! e.hasOwnProperty('offsetX')) {
        var curleft = curtop = 0;
        if (e.offsetParent) {
           var obj=e;
           do {
              curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
              curtop += obj.offsetTop;
           } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        }
        e.offsetX=e.layerX-curleft;
        e.offsetY=e.layerY-curtop;
    }
    return e;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a non-jQuery solution that maintains the same semantics as `offsetX` and `offsetY`.

Comment: Under Firefox 26.0 there is no field named 'offsetParent' in the event (e) thus initial e.offsetParent does not work ('if' is simply ignored). A solution might be to have e.target.offsetParent

Comment: @Alex `e.target.offsetParent` doesn't work either.  Did you come up with a fix for this?

Comment: + 1 - this is the only solution that worked for me, with the only change being using e.target.offsetParent instead of e.offsetParent. I'm using RaphaelJS to draw objects in a map.  With this code, I always get the right mouse coordinates even if e.target is sometimes the circle being drawn and sometimes the map canvas.

Answer (score 11):

There's a bug in Musa's solution: think what happens if `e.offsetX === 0` and `e.layerX === undefined`...

```
var x = e.offsetX || e.layerX; // x is now undefined!
```

A more robust version is as follows:

```
var x = e.hasOwnProperty('offsetX') ? e.offsetX : e.layerX;
var y = e.hasOwnProperty('offsetY') ? e.offsetY : e.layerY;
```

Or, because we can assume that if `offsetX` is defined, `offsetY` will be too:

```
var hasOffset = e.hasOwnProperty('offsetX'),
    x         = hasOffset ? e.offsetX : e.layerX,
    y         = hasOffset ? e.offsetY : e.layerY;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, because the firefox event has 'offsetX/Y' but both are undefined. For what it's worth.

Comment: Bad Mozilla! In that case adjust appropriately - thanks for flagging it up.

Comment: var x = e.offsetX || e.layerX || 0 ; is a simpler solution.

Comment: layerX and offsetX are not the same, if the target is an inline element, the offset give the position of the cursor in the element, but return a layerX relative to his non-inline parent container.

Answer (score 4):

`offset` actually doesn't translate directly into `layer`; the `offset` property doesn't account for the element's margin. The code below should account for this.

```
function(e) {
    var x = e.offsetX, y = e.offsetY;
    if(e.hasOwnProperty('layerX')) {
      x = e.layerX - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
      y = e.layerY - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the non-jquery versions work completely for various reasons. With your help however i got this to work:

```
if(!event.hasOwnProperty('offsetX')) {
    event.offsetX = event.layerX - event.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
    event.offsetY = event.layerY - event.currentTarget.offsetTop;
}
```

Comment: @AdrianMaire - would you care to specify which ones?

Answer (score 3):

I found that all answers posted here *except* the last two answers by EnotionZ and laz brannigan (previously with zero votes each) where wrong in cases where several elements were contained within a div.  In my case I have several canvas elements inside of a single div and I am listening to each canvas separately.

After considerable trial and error the final correct answer I came to, which works perfectly and identically for me in FireFox and Chrome is as follows:

```
//inside my mouse events handler:
var anOffsetX = (inEvent.offsetX !== undefined) ? inEvent.offsetX : (inEvent.layerX - inEvent.target.offsetLeft);
var anOffsetY = (inEvent.offsetY !== undefined) ? inEvent.offsetY : (inEvent.layerY - inEvent.target.offsetTop);
```

Presumably this will also work for margins and such as EnotionZ indicated in his post, but I have not tried that.

Answer (score 2):

But , what you will do if there is not `layerX`,`layerY` fields ?

```
 var xe=e.offsetX,ye=e.offsetY;
  if(!xe){
     xe=e.clientX - $(e.target).offset().left;
  }
  if(!ye){
    ye= e.clientY - $(e.target).offset().top;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

OffsetX/Y behavior is different in FireFox, Chrome/Edge. You may need calculate the value by adding the code snippet:

```
const offsetX = evt.clientX - this.myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().left;
const offsetY = evt.clientY - this.myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

The *myRef* is ref of its nearest parent element. So the offset will be the distance between this element (clientX) minus the one of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

This question needs an updated answer.

---

First, as I mentioned in a comment, regarding all of the older answers using `layerX` and `layerY`:

> "This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."

(Source: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerX](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerX))

---

Second, I've discovered that when you `console.log(event)` in Firefox, `offsetX` and `offsetY` show 0, but when you `console.log(event.offsetX)`, it is not 0. So be careful because you may be being lied to.

This behavior is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#Logging_objects):

> **Logging objects**
>
> Don't use `console.log(obj)`, use `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))`.
>
> This way you are sure you are seeing the value of obj at the moment you log it. Otherwise, **many browsers provide a live view that constantly updates as values change**. This may not be what you want.

(Also note that `JSON.stringify()` will not do what you want here... It doesn't stringify the entire event object.)

Comment: For those who are still having problems with `offsetX` and `offsetY`, you may want to look into this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 0):

If some still needs a solutions this one works perfect in Firefox:

```
var x = e.offsetX || e.originalEvent.layerX;
var y = e.offsetY || e.originalEvent.layerY;
```

Comment: should be noted that this is meant to be used inside a jquery event handler, as jquery wraps the original event in a custom object, with access to the former via ´originalEvent´