# HTML5 with jQuery - e.offsetX is undefined in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, events, undefined

In my HTML5 page, I have a div with `mousemove` event as follows:

```
$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
    xpos = e.offsetX;
    ypos = e.offsetY;
    $('#mouse').html("X : " + xpos + " ; Y : " + ypos);
});
```

It works fine with Google Chrome. But in Firefox, both the are giving the value `undefined`. I have checked it by using Firebug, that is, logged the `e` object to console. Both `offsetX` and `offsetY` are found to be `undefined`.

When I searched in Google, there was a solution saying I should use `layerX` and `layerY`, if both `offsetX` and `offsetY` are undefined.
But from Firebug, I was not able to find it. And even I had given it a try like this:

```
xpos = (e.offsetX==undefined)?e.layerX:e.offsetX;
ypos = (e.offsetY==undefined)?e.layerY:e.offsetY;
```

But that's also giving `undefined` as values.

I am using the most recent jQuery - v1.8.2. And I am testing in my Firefox v14.0.1

Any ideas or suggestions?

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to dystroy and vusan for helping me. The solution to the above issue is as follows:

**SOLUTION**

```
$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
  $('#cursor').show();
  if(e.offsetX==undefined) // this works for Firefox
  {
    xpos = e.pageX-$('#canvas').offset().left;
    ypos = e.pageY-$('#canvas').offset().top;
  }             
  else                     // works in Google Chrome
  {
    xpos = e.offsetX;
    ypos = e.offsetY;
  }
  $('#mouse').html("X : " + xpos + " ; Y : " + ypos);
});
```

Comment: not sure what version of Google Chrome you were using, but it seems to give an undefined object in version Chrome v26 also.

Comment: @cartbeforehorse: I'm using Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m. And it works fine. See it live: http://jsfiddle.net/EEftW/

Comment: I sure got sucked in. Using typescript and StronglyTyped jQuery definition files, I was led to believe OffsetX/Y were parts of jquery. Never realised they were optional and only included in certain browsers. Thanks for your post, you helped me find the problem in a sprawling mess of code.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Firefox

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Firefox 30 - pageX and pageY are always 0

Comment: Wow. Kinda surprised that jQuery doesn't standardise this!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using `layerX` and `layerY` for Firefox and `offsetX` for other browser.

If event fired with jquery:

```
xpos = e.offsetX === undefined ? e.originalEvent.layerX : e.offsetX;
ypos = e.offsetY === undefined ? e.originalEvent.layerY : e.offsetY;
```

If event fired with javascript:

```
xpos = e.offsetX==undefined?e.layerX:e.offsetX;
ypos = e.offsetY==undefined?e.layerY:e.offsetY;
```

Comment: Thanks.. But what I wanted is relative to a container(`#canvas`). pageX/Y are relative to the `<html>` element - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y

Comment: Use `var xInCanvas = e.pageX-$canvas.offset().left;`

Comment: Thanks guys. I got it working when I tried what @dystroy had suggested. The code is as follows: `if(e.offsetX==undefined)
    {
     xpos = e.pageX-$('#canvas').offset().left;
     ypos = e.pageY-$('#canvas').offset().top;
    }    
    else
    {
     xpos = e.offsetX;
     ypos = e.offsetY;
    }`
Thanks again guys :)

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14841138/24874) for a solution that doesn't require jQuery.

Comment: Although pageX and pageY work they do not answer the question directly. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20397642/11792

Comment: pageX is not the same as offsetX

Comment: it's `e.originalEvent.layerX` not `e.layerX`, see other answer(s). And yet no reason to have the same answer 3 times :)

Comment: This answer doesn't work anymore because `e.offsetX` is always `0` and not `undefined` in Firefox.

Answer (score 20):

Use `layerX` and `layerY` in FF and `offsetX` and `offsetY` in all other browsers.

```
$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
  xpos = e.offsetX === undefined ? e.originalEvent.layerX : e.offsetX;
  ypos = e.offsetY === undefined ? e.originalEvent.layerY : e.offsetY;

  $('#mouse').html("X : " + xpos + " ; Y : " + ypos);
});
```

Comment: This and the other answer specifying originalEvent need more upvotes. The "best answer" does provide a solution but these are more accurate as layerX and layerY are more equivalent to offsetX and offsetY. Thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

You did not find them because its in the originalEvent.
try:
e.originalEvent.layerX
e.originalEvent.layerY

About the pageX and pageY they are not calculating the same thing.
layerX is the left of the object from the first relative/absolute parent.
pageX is the left of the object from the page.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in firefox and others.

```
var offsetRequired = (e.offsetX || e.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox actually *does* [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX#Browser_compatibility) `MouseEvent.offsetX` and `MouseEvent.offsetY` after release 39.0, which is released in [july 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_release_history).

Comment: But the values for offsetX/Y in Firefox are not the same as they are in Chrome. Need to convert them but don't know how.

Comment: I'm getting the same values with the newest version of both browsers.

Comment: I have Chrome 49 because my Mac OS is 10.6.8. I can't use a newer version of Chrome until I update my OS (or my boss buys me a new machine).