# Why Firefox event.offsetX and offsetY are undefined?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, cross-browser, offset

I just stumbled upon a bug in my software that happened only on Firefox. The reason was that the event didn't have offsetX and offsetY defined.

I managed to fix it thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334452/event-offsetx-in-firefox#comment22051174_14872192).

Anyways, my question is not a programming help request. I'm just curious why these properties are undefined in Firefox? What is the reason behind it?

I did look through: [DOM3 UIEvent Spec.](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DOM-Level-3-Events/html/DOM3-Events.html#events-UIEvent), [DOM3 MouseEvent Spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-MouseEvent) and [DOM2 MouseEvent Spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MouseEvent).

It appears that neither of the properties are mentioned there, so, I suppose that's an unofficial property introduced in other browsers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although mentioned in the [**W3 specification**](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-mouseevent-interface), the `offsetx`/`offsety` properties themselves are implemented inconsistently across browsers.

While supported in IE, Webkit browsers and Opera, they all function slightly different to the specifications requirements, except for IE - **[according to the "Calculating offsetX, offsetY" section here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/mouse-position/)**.

The properties aren't supported in Firefox at all - it appears to be [**a long-time bug**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69787) that is yet to be resolved.

> "I suppose that's an unofficial property introduced in other
>   browsers?"

I believe it's an official property, that just hasn't been implemented in Firefox. If it was a non-official IE property, it wouldn't have been implemented in the Webkit/Opera browsers, mentioned in the W3 spec nor would Firefox actually be trying to implement it (check out the bug link above).

Comment: FYI: Opera is now a Webkit browser [\[1\]](http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/300-million-users-and-move-to-webkit), [\[2\]](http://business.opera.com/press/releases/general/opera-gears-up-at-300-million-users). And Chrome is not Webkit anymore, it's Blink [1](http://www.chromium.org/blink). And, it seems that Opera is going to follow Chromium, moving also to Blink [\[1\]](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2013/04/04/opera-confirms-it-will-follow-google-and-ditch-webkit-for-blink-as-part-of-its-commitment-to-chromium/).

Comment: @joltmode Whoa, thanks for the links. Looks like I have some catching up to do.

Answer (score 3):

offsetX and offsetY are inconsistent in Firefox so you can do it this way

```
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        rect = target.getBoundingClientRect(),
        offsetX = e.clientX - rect.left,
        offsetY = e.clientY - rect.top;

    console.log([offsetX, offsetY]);
};
```

You can find more info [Here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/mouse-position/) and [here](https://nickthecoder.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/offsetx-and-offsety-in-firefox/)