# Click event coordinates in SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, click, dom-events

This HTML containing SVG:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <svg>
    <g id="polygonGroup" transform="translate(80, 50)">
      <polygon points="-60,-10 -35,-30 -10,-10 -10,30 -60,30"></polygon>
      <polygon points="10,-10 35,-30 60,-10 60,30 10,30"></polygon>
      <polygon class="origin" points="-4,0 0,4 4,0 0,-4"></polygon>
    </g>
    <g id="textGroup" transform="translate(80, 50)">
      <text x="-35" y="10">Text</text>
      <text x="35" y="10">Text</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

and this simple jQuery click event handler:

```
function clicked(event) {
    console.log(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
}

$('svg').click(clicked);
```

as seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/1ht0L8y6/6/ have different behaviors in different browsers:

**Chrome:** The coordinates are based on the top left of the SVG element, no matter where I click inside the SVG. This is the behavior I want.

**Firefox:** The coordinates are based on the top left of whatever element I'm in, which may be SVG, polygon, or text.

**IE and Edge:**

- When in the SVG but not in any of its sub-elements, the coordinates
  are based on the SVG element.
- When in a polygon, the coordinates are
  based on the origin of the `<g>` group, with its `translate` offset
  (i.e., the black diamond). Negative coordinates are possible this way,
  unlike in Chrome or Firefox.
- I have observed a different behavior for
  text elements in these browsers: They would give coordinates based on
  the bottom middle of the text element. But I couldn't manage to
  reproduce this in the fiddle; in the fiddle text elements behave
  the same as polygons in these browsers.

What is a reliable cross-browser way to get the coordinates of the click?

Comment: I can reproduce your problem but I'm afraid it's going to take more time than I have right now to respond to it. You might try this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30708924/3330613

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've added to your code a function to detect the mouse position in SVG.

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('svg')

function clicked(event) {
  let m = oMousePosSVG(event);
    console.log(m.x,m.y);
}

svg.addEventListener("click", clicked)


function oMousePosSVG(e) {
      var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
      p.x = e.clientX;
      p.y = e.clientY;
      var ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
      var p =  p.matrixTransform(ctm);
      return p;
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <svg>
    <g id="polygonGroup" transform="translate(80, 50)">
      <polygon points="-60,-10 -35,-30 -10,-10 -10,30 -60,30"></polygon>
      <polygon points="10,-10 35,-30 60,-10 60,30 10,30"></polygon>
      <polygon class="origin" points="-4,0 0,4 4,0 0,-4"></polygon>
    </g>
    <g id="textGroup" transform="translate(80, 50)" fill="red">
      <text x="-35" y="10">Text</text>
      <text x="35" y="10">Text</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

To read more about mouse detection in SVG I recommend this book: [Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5: Vector Graphics for Web Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076HZ31YZ)

I hope it helps.

Comment: You have 2,279 votes cast and you have never downvoted! Wow! Awesome! You are the first person who I know with this result! 