# Error In Mozilla Firefox.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I write HTML/JS code for HTML5 video player and have a error in Firefox 27.0.1 version, In Ubuntu/Windows Chrome in works, in IE11 it works.

HTML

```
<div id="newprogressBar" style="border:1px solid #aaa; color:#fff; width:295px; height:20px;"><span id="newprogress" style="background-color:#ff0000; height:20px; display:inline-block;"></span></div>
```

JS in HTML

```
var video = document.getElementById("videoPlayer"), (HTML5 <video *.mp4>)
newprogressBar = document.getElementById("newprogressBar");
newprogress = document.getElementById("newprogress");
```

Event function in JS

```
newprogressBar.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
width = parseFloat(newprogressBar.style.width);
var x = event.offsetX / width;  
video.currentTime = Math.round(x * video.duration);
}, false);
```

I have an error on this line in Firefox

```
video.currentTime = Math.round(x * video.duration);
```

Error:

`TypeError: Value being assigned to HTMLMediaElement.currentTime is not a finite floating-point value.`

Comment: What are `x` and `video.duration`?

Comment: Sounds like it's NaNing.

Comment: Looks like a relevant question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334452/event-offsetx-in-firefox

Comment: You should put console.log(width, x, x * video.duration) in your code to see what's going on. I'm sure one of those values is NaN.

Comment: NaN it's true, nut why only in firefox?
x - it's temp variable for debug.
I need to create navigation on video, i see where user click and do thing like this (Max width - selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for .webm video file within video tag. Firefox on linux (also maybe on other OS) doesn't play .mp4 files.

Comment: It needs the gstreamer plugin.