# mousemove grabbing the XY offset of nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the XY position of the mouse in a parent element. That part is simple, what's throwing me off is when there's a nested element, it then grabs the XY position of the mouse in that nested element.

I created a JS Fiddle with a very simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/htenchwv/

You can see how I'm pulling the position with this

```
$(".parent").mousemove(function(event){
    $(".debug").html("X: "+ event.offsetX +"<br>Y: "+ event.offsetY);
});
```

You can see in either the X or Y position, the numbers jump down when you move into the child element. I'm at a loss for why or how I can prevent that behavior and gather ONLY the XY mouse in the parent element

Comment: "X: undefined, Y: undefined" Regards, [Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334452/event-offsetx-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use client X and Y, combined with .offset()

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/htenchwv/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $(".parent").mousemove(function(event){
        var pOffset = $(".parent").offset(),
            px = event.clientX - pOffset.left,
            py = event.clientY - pOffset.top;
        $(".debug").html("X: "+ px +"<br>Y: "+ py);
    });
});
```

HTH

-Ted

Comment: But that gives it relative to the page. Which maybe I'll just have to work around that.

Comment: edited answer, and updated demo to reflect  x/y on the element, accounting for its offset