# Read Pixel Color of georeferenced image and get LatLng

Tags: colors, gis, pixel, geo

I have a colored georeferenced satelliteimage and would like to find out what color has which pixel at which position. All I have is the georeferenced image and average programming skills in php and javascript.

Any idea? Every hint is very welcome :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read Pixel Color of georeferenced image and get LatLng](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585543/read-pixel-color-of-georeferenced-image-and-get-latlng)

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful, it's another stack overflow post on placing an image into HTML5 canvas and then getting the pixel data.

[Getting pixel data from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-color-of-an-image)