# Read Pixel Color of georeferenced image and get LatLng

Tags: php

I have a colored georeferenced satelliteimage and would like to find out what color has which pixel at which position. 
All I have is the georeferenced image and average programming skills in php and javascript.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using any GIS software?  If not, StackOverflow may be a better fit for this question.

Comment: I played around with Quantum Gis, but I would feel more comfortable programming a loop... I will post it also in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

I've not done a lot with PHP and prefer Python to Javascript... but you said every hint is welcome :)

What you may find very useful is the [gdallocationinfo](http://www.gdal.org/gdallocationinfo.html) utility.  Which may do exactly what you need or could be called recursively. Quote from the documentation:

> The gdallocationinfo utility provide a mechanism to query information about a pixel given it's location in one of a variety of coordinate systems.

On the other hand, you may want to 'roll-your-own'. In Python I would use [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) (bindings also available for Java and C#).  For easy array handling I would also use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) (especially look at the latter's [ndimage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) module.  To help you on your way, see [this tutorial](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/) on geoprocessing with GDAL (weeks 4, 5 and 6 are what you want).