# get color of a pixel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get color of a x y pixel with javascript/jquery, so googled and found that it could be done with canvas.

```
var canvas = $("<canvas>"); //Create the canvas element

//Create a layer which overlaps the whole window
canvas.css({ position: "fixed", top: "0", left: "0",
    width: "100%", height: "100%", "z-index": 9001
});

//Add an event listener to the canvas element
canvas.click(function (ev) {
    var x = ev.pageX, y = ev.pageY;
    var canvas = this.getContext("2d");
    canvas.drawWindow(window, x, y, 1, 1, "transparent");
    var data = canvas.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
    var hex = rgb2hex(data[0], data[1], data[2]);
    alert(hex);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

but its not working (`drawWindow` in firefox not working, not working in chrome too).
any ideas ?

Comment: did you actually assigned canvas element to DOM? `$('body').append(canvas);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image

Comment: @Bharadwaj : see its not working http://jsfiddle.net/9SEMf/938/

Comment: @AshokDamani It is not working because the image is from other domain. You will get a security level exception as `The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.` at `getImageData`. Download the image to your project folder and try. I will work & it worked for me.

Comment: @Bharadwaj : awesome it is !!!

Answer (score 1):

`drawWindow` is [a custom JavaScript implementation](http://bgrins.github.io/DrawWindow/). You have to include it before you can use it.

If you are referring to [the native method drawWindow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawWindow%28%29), it cannot be used in a web content that's why it won't work.