# How can I do a colour based hit test for a certain image on a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to know when my mouse pointer is over a certain image, and while in that image, it goes over a very specific colour. Is this possible and how can I do it?

Comment: Yes, this is possible using canvas

Comment: http://paperjs.org/tutorials/images/color-averaging-image-areas/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image

Comment: This got some pretty detailed and very useful answers for a question some little policemen thought should be voted down to -3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I made an attempt. In this example the script searches for the color `#FF0000`, as passed in the options object. http://jsfiddle.net/2sw3pzs4/

```
var ColorChecker = function( options ) {
    var canvas, ctx, output;
    this.init = function() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        output = document.getElementById('output');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        color = this.hexToRGB(options.searchedColor);
        this.drawOnCanvas();

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
            if(e.offsetX) {
                mouseX = e.offsetX;
                mouseY = e.offsetY;
            }
            else if(e.layerX) {
                mouseX = e.layerX;
                mouseY = e.layerY;
            }
            var c = ctx.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1).data;
            var foundColor = [c[0], c[1], c [2]];
            var is_identical = foundColor.join() === color.join();
            var message = is_identical == true ? 'red found' : 'not found';
            output.innerHTML = message;
        });
    }

    this.drawOnCanvas = function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0, 20, 20);
    }

    this.hexToRGB = function( hex ) {
        var r = parseInt((this.cutHex(hex)).substring(0,2),16);
        var g = parseInt((this.cutHex(hex)).substring(2,4),16);
        var b = parseInt((this.cutHex(hex)).substring(4,6),16);

        return [r,g,b];
    }

    this.cutHex = function( hex ) {
         return hex.replace("#",'');
    }
    this.init();
}

var colorChecker = new ColorChecker({
    searchedColor: "#FF0000",
});
```

If you want to use an image just use `putImageData()` to draw the image on the canvas. You can use the function drawOnCanvas in my code to draw whatever you want inside the canvas, or resize it or other stuff.

Comment: It's working great, thanks, but outside Visual Studio, my canvas +image just appear as a small red square the top left of the screen. In Visual Studio it works a charm.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're saying. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, I had another problem that was drawing a small red square on my canvas after I drew my image. It wasn't my code and I was unaware of it, so I thought it was a problem with my code.

Comment: Oh yes the red square is just me drawing a test square on the canvas, just remove the ctx.fillStyle and ctx.fillRect parts in my code

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote this :

Basically, it does what @nepeo told you to do.
+ it cleans up the canvas and reset the original image after calculations.
+ I also added a customized cursor that you can disable.

---

**Usage** : Set your own callback function in `colorPicker.callback`, then attach the `colorPicker.init` function on the `mouseover` event of desired image.

**N.B** : You will have to host the images on your own server or to convert them to base64 in order to use this script.

---

```js
var colorPicker = function() {};
//Settings

colorPicker.radius = 1, //square px

colorPicker.customCursor = true; 

colorPicker.cursorColor = '#FFF';

//the fomatting for color return : "hex" || "rgba" || "array"
// !! hex is upperCase and returns "transparent" if opacity == 0; rgba is 'rgba(r,g,b,a)';  array is '[r,g,b,a]'
colorPicker.colorFormat = "hex";

//What to do with that color? Edit this to whatever you want
colorPicker.callback = function (color) {
    var res = document.getElementById('ColorPickerResult');
    res.style.backgroundColor = color;
    res.style.color = invertHex(color);
    res.innerHTML = color;
    //Here I'm searching for some Hex color
    if (color == '#FC771F') {
        res.innerHTML = '!!! Found some orange !!!';
    }
}

//What to do when we leave the image (Additionally to reset the original image)
colorPicker.callbackOut = function(){
    var res = document.getElementById('ColorPickerResult');
    res.innerHTML = '';
  }

//END Settings

//This is optional
colorPicker.setCursor = function (canvas) {
    if (!colorPicker.setCursor) return;
    var can = document.createElement('canvas');
    can.width = colorPicker.radius;
    can.height = colorPicker.radius;
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    ctx.strokeStyle = colorPicker.cursorColor;
    ctx.rect(0, 0, colorPicker.radius, colorPicker.radius);
    ctx.stroke();
    canvas.style.cursor = 'url("' + can.toDataURL("image/png") + '"),default';
}
colorPicker.Init = function () {
    var img = this;
    var can = document.createElement('canvas');
    can.id = 'ColorPicker';
    can.width = img.width;
    can.height = img.height;
    can.ori = img;
    can.oridisp = img.style.display;
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    can.addEventListener('mousemove', colorPicker.pick);
    can.addEventListener('mouseout', colorPicker.out);
    colorPicker.setCursor(can);
    img.parentNode.insertBefore(can, img);
    img.style.display = 'none';
};
colorPicker.pick = function (evt) {
    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    ctx = this.getContext('2d'),
    imageData = ctx.getImageData(evt.clientX - rect.left, evt.clientY - rect.top, colorPicker.radius, colorPicker.radius);
    data = imageData.data;
    r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        r += data[i];
        g += data[++i];
        b += data[++i];
        a += data[++i];
    }
    var p = data.length / 4;

    var mR = function (i) {
        return Math.round(i);
    };
    r = mR(r/p);
    g = mR(g/p);
    b = mR(b/p);
    a = (mR((a/p)/255 * 100)/100).toFixed(2);
  
    if(colorPicker.colorFormat === "hex"){
      var color = colorPicker.toHex(r,g,b,a);
      }
    else if(colorPicker.colorFormat === "rgba"){
      var color = 'rgba('+r+', '+g+', '+b+', '+a+')';
      }
    else if(colorPicker.colorFormat === "array"){
      var color = [r, g, b, a];
      }
 
    colorPicker.callback(color);
}
colorPicker.out = function () {
    this.ori.style.display = this.oridisp;
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    colorPicker.callbackOut();
}

//toHex function originally posted by http://stackoverflow.com/users/10474/felipec in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19765382/3702797
colorPicker.toHex= function(r,g,b,a){
        if(a=="0.00") return "transparent";
        var rgb = b | (g << 8) | (r << 16);
        return '#' + (0x1000000 + rgb).toString(16).slice(1).toUpperCase()
  }
// END colorPicker \\

// Just an example of external function beeing called 
function invertHex(c){
  if(c==="transparent") return "#000000";
  c = c.replace('#', '');
  var reqHex = "#";
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        reqHex = reqHex + (15-parseInt(c[i],16)).toString(16);
    }
    return reqHex;
}

//Attach the function to whatever images you want
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', colorPicker.Init);
```

```css
body {
    background: #175;
}
```

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
<span id="ColorPickerResult"></span>
```

Comment: In your script, how do you give an indication of what colour to look for, like `var colorChecker = new ColorChecker({ searchedColor: "#FF0000", });` in @Jonas's script?

Comment: It's in the `colorPicker.callback`. But the color is formatted in rgba(), in the example, I'm looking for `rgba(252, 119, 31, 1.00)` (#fc771f). you could add an rgba to hex function call in the callback too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a canvas instead of the image, resize the canvas to the size of the image and draw the image into the canvas.

Then you can get the pixel location of the cursor using the canvas.onmousemove event. Canvas may have something in it's api for querying the colour at a location(can't remember at this moment) but otherwise you can use getImageData to get the rgba data for every pixel and do a look up during the event. Ta da!