# transparent image background using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to remove/delete an image's background (white background) using jQuery/javascript?

I know it is possible to do this using PHP and ImageMagick but I do not have ImageMagick installed on my shared hosting and it would be a lot easier to find a jQuery solution if it is possible.

Comment: These two may get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331068/crop-image-using-a-crop-tools-to-crop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image

Answer (score 0):

You can draw you image in a `canvas` and instead of white draw transparent.

Comment: i don't really want to use HTML5 if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: Yes, I am. If you want to do advanced things you have to use advanced technologies.