# Is it possible to retrieve the top left pixel colour of an image with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am currently using this code to set a div's image background:

```
$('.sample_image').css('background-image', 'url('+ $(this).attr("src") +')');
```

We use this so when a user clicks on an image colour swatch, it sets that as the background image so they can get a better view of a product.

The issue is that some image swatches have 2 colours, to show a secondary colour. I need to just display the colour which is on the left hand side (top left pixel.)

Is this possible with JQuery?

Comment: it is possible, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `<canvas>`,  so no,  not just using jQuery.

Basically you transfer your image to a canvas element, and then you can work with it from there.  There may be plugins that do this,  but it's only going to work on modern browsers.