# How do I take grayscale values of an image and put it into an array of pixels? (html canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas

Is it possible to do this with html canvas?

With this

```
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
      var grayscale = data[i]*0.2126 + data[i +1]*0.7152 + data[i +2]*0.0722;
      data[i]     = grayscale; // red
      data[i + 1] = grayscale; // green
      data[i + 2] = grayscale; // blue
    }
```

I iterate over all pixel and grayscale them. I know how to convert that into a base64 code but waht if I only want the gray values of the image instead of the whole RGB image?

Comment: Explain more please.

Comment: I want to llop through the image data, calculate each pixel and add it to a string. is that possible?

Comment: Okay, so you have an existing image & you want to get the image data into an array?

Comment: check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image

Comment: sorry i was wrong, what I meant, I grayscale a picture and I only want the grayscale values of the image as a string instead of the whole color picture I updated my question, sorry for the confusion !

Comment: I want that in order to to get a smaller sized image. Since it's grayscaled I don't want the color channels, is that possible?

Comment: You could (1) Save your remaining grayscale values to a `Uint8Array`, (2) Stringify that array with `var s=myUint8Array.toString()`, (3) Base64 encode that string with `btoa(s)`.  My question is what are you going to use that result for?