# Jquery find color of top left pixel image

Tags: jquery

Is there a way with JQuery to find the  first pixel top/left color of an image ?

thank you

Comment: No. jQuery is not an image processing tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP you can find it and include in your HTML before sending it to the client. http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php

Put it in a data-pixelColor element for re-use in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer: [How to get a pixel's x,y coordinate color from an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image)

You can draw a canvas, load the image into it and read the top-left 1x1 pixel using [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData).

> The CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData() method of the Canvas 2D
>   API returns an ImageData object representing the underlying pixel data
>   for the area of the canvas denoted by the rectangle which starts at
>   (sx, sy) and has an sw width and sh height.

The function return an `ImageData` object, accessing [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data) property you'll get the pixel information.

> The readonly ImageData.data property returns a Uint8ClampedArray
>   representing a one-dimensional array containing the data in the RGBA
>   order, with integer values between 0 and 255 (included).

Code:

```
var myImg = new Image();
myImg.src = '../img/logo.png';
var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0);
console.log(context.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2v7ksm7c/