# How To Sense Colors From an img with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a shooter simulator(ish). I have a silhouette of a person with a white background. I have it so you can shoot it. I would like the bullets to stop at the beginning of the sillhouette. You can see it here:

```
codepen.io/TheAndersMan/pen/WRNEmR?editors=0011
```

Feel free to change any of the code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: You should use vector shapes instead of an image.

Comment: @kiran.koduro sorry, I am working on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020#answer-8751659).

Version without jQuery [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9SEMf/1952/):

```
img = document.getElementById("image")
output = document.getElementById("output")

img.onmousemove = function(e) {

  if (!this.canvas) {
    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.canvas.width = this.width;
    this.canvas.height = this.height;
    this.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
  }

  var pixelData = this.canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

  output.innerHTML = 'R: ' + pixelData[0] + '<br>G: ' + pixelData[1] + '<br>B: ' + pixelData[2] + '<br>A: ' + pixelData[3];

};
```

Don't use images from other sites as it might be blocked.

<strike>**Update**: code without almost any jQuery [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9SEMf/1951/). Update coming.</strike>

Comment: Can you give me a version with no jQuery? I don't mean to sound ungrateful, but I prefer to use vanilla JS.

Comment: Questions with no `jQuery` tagged should be answered without the latter usage involved. :)

Comment: Thanks @AdamAzad. Vanilla JS version added.

Comment: @ChrisHappy this question is pretty much a duplicate of the question linked, you shouldn't answer questions like this.

Comment: @JacobGray The other question provided a jQuery solution, I think I provided a different solution based on the code of another question.

Comment: @ChrisHappy it's a question about canvas. The concept, and the code that gets the color is the exact same no matter what the OP is using.