# HTML5 Canvas - How to get adjacent pixels position from the linearized imagedata Uint8ClampedArray?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

A 5 by 5 pixel image data is something like this in linearized imagedata array-

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 240, **0, 0, 0, 255**, 0, 0, 0, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

So, the 3x3 pixel data is- 0 0 0 255. How can I get the adjacent pixel positions? Left and right adjacent ones are easy, just minus 4 and plus 4 respectively.

Comment: You need to know the dimensions of the image, then it's easy as well - just minus 4*size and plus 4*size respectively.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, image dimensions are easy to retrieve through image.width and image.height as I am using Image() constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Accessing pixel data

The pixel data from [`.getImageData().data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) is a [`TypedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) of type [`Uint8ClampedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray). When reading the values they will be in the range 0-255 and in the order Red, Green, Blue, Alpha. If the value of alpha is zero then red, green, and blue will also be zero.

To get the index of a pixel

```
const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
var index = (x + y * imageData.width) * 4;
const red   = imageData.data[index];
const green = imageData.data[index + 1];
const blue  = imageData.data[index + 2];
const alpha = imageData.data[index + 3];
```

To move down one pixel

```
index += imageData.width * 4;
```

To move up one

```
index -= imageData.width * 4;
```

To move left.

```
index -= 4;
```

To move right

```
index += 4;
```

If you are on the left or right edge and you move in the direction of the edge you will wrap around, on the line above and to the right if moving left and the line below and on the left if moving down.

When setting the image data the values will be floored and clamped to 0-255

```
 imageData.data[index] = 29.5
 console.log(imageData.data[index]); // 29

 imageData.data[index] = -283
 console.log(imageData.data[index]); // 0

 imageData.data[index] = 283
 console.log(imageData.data[index]); // 255
```

If you set an index that is outside the array size it will be ignored

```
 imageData.data[-100] = 255;
 console.log(imageData.data[-100]); // Undefined
 imageData.data[imageData.data.length + 4] = 255;
 console.log(imageData.data[imageData.data.length + 4]); // Undefined
```

You can speed up access and processing by using different array types. For example all of a pixel's channels as one value using [`Uint32Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint32Array)

```
const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
const pixels = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer);
var index32 = x + y * imageData.width;  // note there is no 4*;

const pixel = pixels[index32];
```

The channels are stored in bits 31-24 Alpha, 23-16 Blue, 15-8 Green, 7-0 Red.

You can set a pixel using a hex value

```
 pixels[x + y * imageData.width] = 0xFF0000FF;  // red 
 pixels[x + y * imageData.width] = 0xFF00FF00;  // Green 
 pixels[x + y * imageData.width] = 0xFFFF0000;  // Blue 
 pixels[x + y * imageData.width] = 0xFF000000;  // Black 
 pixels[x + y * imageData.width] = 0xFFFFFFFF;  // White
 pixels[x + y * imageData.width] = 0;  // Transparent
```

You can set all the pixels in a single call

```
 pixels.fill(0xFF000000); // all pixels black
```

You can copy array data onto the array with

```
 // set 3 pixels in a row at x,y Red, Yellow, White
 pixels.set([0xFF0000FF,0xFF00FFFF,0xFFFFFFFF], x+y * imageData.width);
```

#### Warning

If the canvas has any pixel/s that are from an untrusted source it will be tainted and you will not be able to read the pixel data. Trusted sources are same domain or images served with the appropriate CORS header information. Images that are on the file system can not have their pixels accessed. Once a canvas is tainted it can not be cleaned.

A tainted canvas will throw an error when you call `ctx.getImageData(0,0,1,1,)` MDN does not list this exception for some reason. You will see   "SecurityError" DOMException; in the DevTools console and there are plenty of answered question here in StackOverflow on the subject.

Comment: Yes, so adjacent pixels are: index - imageData.width * 4 - 4, index - imageData.width * 4,  index - imageData.width * 4 + 4, index - 4, index + 4, index + imageData.width * 4 - 4, index + imageData.width * 4,  index + imageData.width * 4 + 4. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the index with the width of the matrix and the length of one unit of `4`.

The access is zero based.

```js
function getPos(array, x, y, width) {
    var p = 4 * (x + y * width);
    return array.slice(p, p + 4);
}

var array = [
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 240, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 241, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ];

// element above
console.log(JSON.stringify(getPos(array, 2, 1, 5))); // [0, 0, 0, 240]

// actual element
console.log(JSON.stringify(getPos(array, 2, 2, 5))); // [0, 0, 0, 255]

// element below
console.log(JSON.stringify(getPos(array, 2, 3, 5))); // [0, 0, 0, 241]
```

Comment: Diagonals are not adjacent?

Comment: just take the coordinates and then you get the values.

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz that's a nice way to access pixels as a matrix like way.