# Swapping red and green?

Tags: javascript

When I execute this code, only the green value gets swapped. The red value remains the same. Why is that and what should I do?

Intial RGB: 90:123:92
New RGB should be: 123:90:92
Right now, I get: 90:90:92

```
var img = new SimpleImage("smalllion.jpg");
var pix = img.getPixel(0,0);
print(img)
print("orginal rgb " + pix)

function swapRedGreen(pixel){
    for(var pixel of img.values()){
        var newG = pixel.getRed();
        pixel.setGreen(newG)
        var newR = pixel.getGreen();
        pixel.setRed(newR);
    }
}
swapRedGreen("smalllion.jpg")
print(img)
var pix1 = img.getPixel(0,0);
print(pix1)
```

Comment: you read green just after you changed it to the red value

Comment: something tells me that manipulating directly pixeldata this operation will be 10x faster. Good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**: This might be because in line 9, you assign pixel the green value, which you then retrieve in line 10 to convert into red. You are essentially converting red --> green, and then green --> red.

**Solution**: Try switching line 9 and 10.

Comment: Ok, so that is how it works. In my initial code, the value gets stored in green then, the red stores the new green value. 
 thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is when you called `var newR = pixel.getGreen();`, the `green` is already being set to the `red` color. Instead store the original green & red to variables at the beginning.

Try this instead:

```
function swapRedGreen(pixel) {
    for (var pixel of img.values()) {
        var oldRed = pixel.getRed();
        var oldGreen = pixel.getGreen();

        pixel.setGreen(oldRed);
        pixel.getRed(oldGreen);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, i need to save the value first then store it.
Thanks.