# Javascript - How i get pixel color of a image?

Tags: javascript

I searched for this but did not find anything didactic, I need someone to explain how I get the pixel of a coordinate: x, y of an image.

Sorry my ask, i'm new in this site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a similar question and answer on SO about this. Basically, you'll create a canvas representation of your PNG, from there you can select the color of each pixel.

[How to get a pixel's x,y coordinate color from an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image)