# Detect path around nontransparent part of image on canvas

Tags: javascript, image, ionic-framework, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm drawing an image onto a canvas using drawImage. It's a PNG that is surrounded by transparent pixels, like this:

[image]

How can I detect a path to the visible part of that image on the canvas?

Check it out full code on [Github](https://github.com/gokujy/ioniccanvas.github.io)

Check it out live demo [IonCanvas](https://ioncanvas.sitesforhosting.co.in/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751659/916000 may help you.

Comment: What do you want to do with that "path"? There are many solutions to this problem, each dependent on the real needs.

Comment: I want to show accuracy using draw path(use pen/ brush etc). In image 1 is black and the background of the image is transparent. I want to detect if a user draws in a transparent part,  show alert or something like I will show.

Comment: please check question i added live link of demo and code on git