# Tracking mouse hover on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, graphics2d

does anyone know if pixel color tracking on mouse hover can be done with html5 canvas to get the same results in the video below?

[player tracking hover example](https://web-intel.com/files/CanvasTest.webm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate of [How to get a pixel's x,y coordinate color from an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image)

The top answer on that article provides a good explanation, as well as [links this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/9SEMf/869/) with some code that does exactly what you are looking for.  I have also included the JS portion below which has a dependency on jquery

```js
$(function() {

    $('img').mousemove(function(e) {

        if(!this.canvas) {
            this.canvas = $('<canvas />')[0];
            this.canvas.width = this.width;
            this.canvas.height = this.height;
            this.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
        }

        var pixelData = this.canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

        $('#output').html('R: ' + pixelData[0] + '<br>G: ' + pixelData[1] + '<br>B: ' + pixelData[2] + '<br>A: ' + pixelData[3]); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph, i'm trying to find a way to ignore the greens and hover a circle under a player.