# How to know the color of an element on click in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use a chart library called nivo. 
I need to trigger a function each time I click on a specific part of the chart.

To this purpose, I believe it would be efficient to "capture" the pixel color of the clicked element and then trig the right function thanks to this information.

The chart is a high level component that renders a svg on the DOM. A div wraps it.

I think I need to know the position of my mouse within the scope of this component (there could be several charts on the same page, so no `document.addEventListener`). Here is my code:

```js
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ResponsiveStream data={series} keys={keys}/>
    </div>);
};
```

How to know the color of the clicked element?

Comment: It can't work, because I need to know the color of any part of a svg element when I click on it. This method is to get the background color of a div.

Comment: Yes I saw you updated your question, I'll remove the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ResponsiveStream doesn't take any event handlers nor ref](https://github.com/plouc/nivo/blob/master/packages/stream/index.d.ts)

In that case you can either send feature request in their [github page](https://github.com/plouc/nivo/issues) and use pure js.

```js
const Component = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null)

  const onChartMouseMove = ({target, screenX, screenY}) => {
    const rect = target.getBoundingClientRect(); // perhaps you'd like to get relative position of mouse from the element
    console.log(rect.left - screenX, rect.top - screenY);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = containerRef && containerRef.current;

    if(element) {
      const svg = element.querySelector("svg");

      svg.addEventListener("mousemove", onChartMouseMove)

      return () => {
        svg.removeEventListener("mousemove", onChartMouseMove);
      }
    }
  }, [containerRef])

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      <ResponsiveStream data={series} keys={keys}/>
    </div>);
};
```

**--Edit**

Unfortunately `nivo` doesnt have umd bundle so I prepared a sample component rendering an xml with logic above.

Getting the color is more difficult as you have to [convert svg to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser) then put Image on canvas via [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) and call [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData)

Now with [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) you have to compute index where the element is located. `MouseEvent.offsetX`, `MouseEvent.offsetY` can help you with that.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image)

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

const getValues = () => Array(400).fill(0).map((pr, index) => ({
  id: index,
  row: index % 20,
  column: Math.floor(index / 20),
  value: index * 16000
}))

const getImageDataFromSvg = (svg) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const svgXml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);

  const image = new Image();
  image.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(svgXml);
  image.onload = function() {
      
      const width = image.naturalWidth;
      const height = image.naturalHeight;
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = width;
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      resolve(context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height));
  }  
})

const ResponsiveStream = () => {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(getValues());

  const fill = (value) => {
    return '#' + ("000000" + value.toString(16)).substr(-6);
  }

  return <svg width="200" height="200">
    {colors.map(pr => <rect fill={fill(pr.value)} x={pr.row * 10} y={pr.column * 10} width={10} height={10} key={pr.id}></rect>)}
  </svg>
}

const App = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null)

  const onChartMouseMove = ({target, offsetX, offsetY}, imageData) => {
    
    let index = (offsetY * imageData.width  + offsetX) * 4;
    const [red, green, blue, alpha] = imageData.data.slice(index, index + 4);
    const hex = '#' + red.toString(16)
    + green.toString(16)
    + blue.toString(16)
    console.log(hex);
        
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let isUnmounted = false;
    let func = null;
    const element = containerRef && containerRef.current;

    if(element) {
      const svg = element.querySelector("svg");
      
      getImageDataFromSvg(svg)
        .then(imageData => {
          if(isUnmounted) {
            return;
          }
          
          func = (event) => onChartMouseMove(event, imageData)
          svg.addEventListener("mousemove", func)    
        })
      
      return () => {
        isUnmounted = true;
        svg.removeEventListener("mousemove", func);
      }
    }
  }, [containerRef])


return <div>
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      <ResponsiveStream/>
    </div>
</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-ui-lab-umd@4.0.0-alpha.32/material-ui-lab.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

--Edit

You have to wrap code in `setTimeout` if rendering takes some time.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let isUnmounted = false;
    let func = null;
    let svg = null
    const element = chartRef && chartRef.current;
    if (element) {

      setTimeout(() => {
        svg = element.querySelector("svg");
        getImageDataFromSvg(svg).then(imageData => {
          if (isUnmounted) {
            return;
          }
          func = event => onChartMouseMove(event, imageData);
          svg.addEventListener("mousemove", func);
        });
      }, 0)

      return () => {
        isUnmounted = true;
        if(svg) {
          svg.removeEventListener("mousemove", func);
        }
      };
    }
  }, [chartRef]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just changed one line so the app doesn't crash   svg && svg.addEventListener("mousemove", onChartMouseMove(element)); . I also added const before onChartMouseMove. But the function is never triggered. Also, it would just give me the position of my mouse, how would you retrieve the color of the clicked element then?

Comment: Updated answer and provided a snippet. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Józef, thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it. Your last block of code works when generating colors inside a svg, but when I replace it by a real Nivo's streamchart, I have a blank page. Here is your updated code with the streamchart in a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-haslett-g4hwv?file=/src/App.js . What's missing?

Comment: I wrapped what's inside the `if(element) {` in `setTimeout(() => { <code> }, 10)` and it worked. Updated answer