# Show image pixel by pixel with JQuery

Tags: jquery, image

I have an image; I want to get each pixel of this image and show it pixel by pixel (something like an image effect).

Is there a way to show an image pixel by pixel with jQuery?

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041399/how-to-use-javascript-or-jquery-to-read-a-pixel-of-an-image

Comment: If you're serious about this, http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-image-processing/.. sniff on this :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041399/how-to-use-javascript-or-jquery-to-read-a-pixel-of-an-image