# Is there any way to select a free formed image?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, svg

Is there any way to select a free formed image?

http://www.ismfilms.com/diagram/diagramAS3.swf

For example,am trying to convert this flash into html5.
I need to select each one of those images.

Any idea guys??

Comment: I haven't used Fabric.js but it seems to be useful for this kind of problem: http://fabricjs.com/  
Here you have an example: http://fabricjs.com/per-pixel-drag-drop/

Comment: Please see this link i think useful for you https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/     and https://pixelplant.com/

Comment: @BipinKumarPal Thnx for the help,but i have already looked through those.
I want to do this on my own,and not use any softwares.
Just the plain logic would be more than helpful. :)
Thnx again.

Comment: Then paint the image and look at the coords when the mouse enters the canvas... what have you tried?

Comment: @TheBronx I tried using a z-index logic,which was completely stupid of me.
Now am trying a simple logic of conversion of the svg images of those flash file to canvas code.
That way i can select each image.. i think.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't "select" images in a canvas, it's not that easy. You can get the coords of the mouse, and calculate which image should be selected. That's hard, and that's why Fabric.js exists. But you can write your own code...

Comment: @TheBronx I havent tried out fabric.js yet,learning..
The mouse coordinates logic,well considering the flash file that i gave,its gna get complicated.

Using the canvas ,i was thinking about putting up images as objects much similar to the selection in here using kinetic.js:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-expand-image-on-hover/

Comment: Sorry your question was closed...You have an interesting an relevant question: How do we take existing Flash projects and convert them to html projects?  While this question is probably too broad for Stackoverflow, it is certainly relevant.  A suggestion: since you have the svg paths already, create html SVG elements from those paths.  The benefit is you can do precise hittesting of their irregular paths and it's a simple matter to use javascript to manipulate the hover effect and respond to clicks.  Since you don't want to use libraries, html canvas would be a harder conversion path to take.

Comment: @markE Am gonna try and use that Fabric.js.
Am a newbie btw... so will take time.
Thanx for your help ppl :)

Comment: Cool!  I would have suggested FabricJS because it handles incoming SVG very well, but you commented that you didn't want to use libraries. Good luck with your conversion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Fabric.js. But, if that's not an option, I would create all images, in png format and with the same width and height as the canvas.

Then I would draw all images in the canvas.

When the mouse enters the canvas, get the coords and **check that pixel on every image** until you find a non-transparent pixel. When that happens, repaint the canvas with that image selected.

But, how can you check the pixels of an image from javascript? It seems you can only do that drawing the image on a canvas, alone ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041399/how-to-use-javascript-or-jquery-to-read-a-pixel-of-an-image) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image)). But your images are going to be the same all the time so you can generate that information previously: create a matrix of 0's (transparent pixel) and 1's for each image, and that's it, save all matrix in an array and use that information when the mouse enters the canvas.

Some pseudocode:

```
paint() {
    for (image in images) {
        if (image.isSelected) {
            canvas.draw( image, opacity=1.0 )
        } else {
            canvas.draw( image, opacity=0.5 )
        }
    }
}

canvas.on("mouseover") {
    unselectAllImages();
    coords = getCoords();
    for (var i=0; i<matrixArray.length; i++) {
        matrix = matrixArray[i];
        if ( matrix[coords.x, coords.y]!=0 ) {
            //you have found a non-transparent pixel in this image
            //that means this is the image going to be selected
            images[i].isSelected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

canvas.on("mouseout") {
    unselectAllImages();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way**: You can assign different colours to each region and save these colors. When use clicks/hover mouse, you check color and get region, that you repaint.

**Using hidden info**: If you **can not** use different colours, consider using very very similar colors, where for example red component is same, blue same, but green has +1 offset. For example these colors (or regions in image) looks same for human, but not for PC:

```
#007eff
#007dff
#007cff
#007bff
#007aff
#0079ff
```

[image]

*How many different blue colors you see?*

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to do the work and define each shape as a set of JS drawing instructions - ctx.startPath(), ctx.moveTo(), ctx.arcTo(), etc - then you can use the following logic to detect which shape your cursor is hovering over:

```
get current cursor coordinates
for each shape {
    draw shape - but don\'t stroke or fill it
    use ctx.isPointInPath(coordinates) to check if cursor is over shape
    if true
        draw/fill shape with highlight colors
    if false
        draw/fill shape with normal colors for that shape
```

... but if you're wanting to recreate the SWF animation linked to in the OP, I think your best bet is to use a dedicated canvas library or (Fabric, Easel, Raphael, etc); alternatively, see if you could achieve better results using a different technology such as SVG.

Here's my demo of a world map: http://scrawl.rikweb.org.uk/demo014.html

Answer (score 0):

I think SVG is perfect for this. You'd have to re-draw the graphics in a vector graphics program (or write the SVG by hand), then you can group the corresponding elements together, create hover effects via CSS and add JavaScript events. Maybe something along [these lines](http://jsbin.com/UMuMaDE/1/):

```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="170 220 325 260" width="100%" height="100%">
     <style type="text/css">
        #A rect, #A path{
          fill:#c73c43;
        }
        #B rect, #B path {
          fill:#c7bc3c;
        }
        #C rect, #C path {
          fill: #3cc757     
        }
        g:hover rect, g:hover path {
          opacity: .7;
        }
     </style>
     <g id="B">
        <path
           d="m 434.15266,258.14294 c 29.87306,26.36958 60.00494,102.39977 45.97576,102.54668 l -130.94303,1.37121 z"/>
        <rect width="139.40105" height="40.406101" x="339.08868" y="158.4413"
           transform="matrix(0.87295361,0.48780323,-0.48780323,0.87295361,0,0)"/>
        <text x="251.52798" y="365.45844">B</text>
        <text x="400.52548" y="336.6691">B</text>
     </g>
     <g id="C">
        <path
           d="m 316.27906,227.87286 c 39.26266,-6.79694 117.42057,17.28332 108.75529,28.31746 l -80.8785,102.98848 z"/>
        <text x="344.46201" y="285.6564">C</text>
     </g>
     <g id="A">
        <path
           d="m 219.2031,296.76808 c 20.20305,-34.34519 89.10998,-78.39462 91.92389,-64.64976 l 26.26396,128.28937 z"/>
        <path
           d="m 194.5067,461.78603 c -13.60455,-37.45226 -3.66352,-118.62918 8.72407,-112.04233 l 115.62118,61.47927 z"/>
        <text x="211.12189" y="403.84424">A</text>
        <text x="262.63965" y="305.85944">A</text>
     </g>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(
          document.getElementsByTagName("g"),
          function(gElement){
            gElement.addEventListener("click", function(event){
              alert(gElement.getAttribute("id"));
            });
          }
        );
     </script>
  </svg>
```