# Getting the color value of a pixel on click of a mesh with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, getimagedata

I'm working with the last version of three.js and I got a scene with a 2D mesh, with gradient color. The color depends of a value assigned to each vertex. I would like to get the value of every point of my gradient by clicking on it with the mouse (by getting the color, and make some math for my value)

I tried to use a system like this one, since it works here : http://jsbin.com/wepuca/2/edit?html,js,output

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function echoColor(e){
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(e.pageX, e.pageX, 1, 1);
    red = imgData.data[0];
    green = imgData.data[1];
    blue = imgData.data[2];
    alpha = imgData.data[3];
    console.log(red + " " + green + " " + blue + " " + alpha);  
}
```

My problem is that this technique is used to get data from the canvas, when an image is displayed, and not a mesh. When I tried to use it on my mesh, I have that error :

"TypeError: ctx is null" or "imageData is not a function" (depending on how I declared my canvas and his context).

Since I didn't find if this method can be used with mesh, I'm here asking if it's possible or not, more than how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433305/threejs-how-to-pick-the-intersection-point-color-of-an-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you cannot get a 2D context from a canvas which is already using a WebGL context. This is why you're getting the `ctx is null` error.

To get the pixel color, you have two options.

**1. Transfer the WebGL canvas image onto a canvas with a 2D context.**

To do this, create a new canvas and size it to be the same size as your THREE.js canvas, and get a 2D context from it. You can then draw the rendered image from the THREE.js canvas onto your new canvas as an image, using the 2D context:

```
var img2D = new Image();
twoDeeCanvasImage.addEventListener("load", function () {
    ctx2D.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2D.width, canvas2D.height);
    ctx2D.drawImage(img2D, 0, 0);
    // from here, get your pixel data
});
img2D.src = renderer.domElement.toDataURL("img/png");
```

From there you can use `getImageData`, like you did before.

One caveat of this method is that you may see image degradation due to compression introduced when exporting the image via `toDataURL`. You can circumvent this in some cases:

```
if(ctx2D.imageSmoothingEnabled !== undefined){
    ctx2D.imageSmoothingEnabled  = false;
}
else if(ctx2D.mozImageSmoothingEnabled  !== undefined){
    ctx2D.mozImageSmoothingEnabled   = false;
}
else if(ctx2D.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled  !== undefined){
    ctx2D.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled   = false;
}
else{
    console.warn("Browser does not support disabling canvas antialiasing. Results image may be blurry.");
}
```

**2. You can also get a pixel value directly from the renderer, but it will cost you an extra render pass.**

See this THREE.js example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=instanc#webgl_interactive_instances_gpu

This example uses `readRenderTargetPixels` in the `THREE.WebGLRenderer`. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer

I don't have any personal experience using this method, so hopefullysomeone else can fill in some of the blanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm working on the example you gave me. I don't know if I will succeed, but I know that what I was trying to do won't work !

Comment: @WestLangley where do I get the renderTarget from? 
I have a normal webgl scene without a renderTarget yet.

Comment: @vinni Please look at the code for the example WestLangley linked. If you still have questions, please create a new question by using the "Ask a question" button.

Comment: @TheJim01, I realize this may be a long shot, but - if you, or anybody, remembers the link to the code that WestLangley linked, or what the name of the example was, could you please re-post?  WestLangley's post seems to have disappeared completely.

Comment: @astro_bear I'm sorry, I do not remember. There was no guarantee the link was still good anyway. Three.js has also evolved since 2017. I recommend creating a new question to focus on your specific implementation.